# What is the best way to calculate Age using Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript

What is the best way to calculate Age using Flex?

Answer (score 13):

I found an answer at [the bottom of this page in comments section (which is now offline)](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=08_Dates_and_times_164_2.html).

> **jpwrunyan said on Apr 30, 2007 at 10:10 PM :**
>
> > By the way, here is how to calculate age in years (only) from DOB without needing to account for leap years:

With a slight correction by [Fine-Wei Lin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/210612/fine-wei-lin), the code reads

```
private function getYearsOld(dob:Date):uint {  
    var now:Date = new Date();  
    var yearsOld:uint = Number(now.fullYear) - Number(dob.fullYear);  
    if (dob.month > now.month || (dob.month == now.month && dob.date > now.date)) 
    {
       yearsOld--;
    }
    return yearsOld;  
}
```

> > This handles most situations where you need to calculate age.

Answer (score 3):

```
var userDOB : Date = new Date(year,month-1,day);
var today : Date = new Date();

var diff : Date = new Date();
diff.setTime( today.getTime() - userDOB.getTime() );

var userAge : int = diff.getFullYear() - 1970;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it roughly the same as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c): (translated to AS3)

```
var age:int = (new Date()).fullYear - bDay.fullYear;
if ((new Date()) < (new Date((bDay.fullYear + age), bDay.month, bDay.date))) age--;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little more complex calculation, this calculates age in years and months. Example: User is 3 years 2 months old.

```
private function calculateAge(dob:Date):String {        
    var now:Date = new Date();

    var ageDays:int = 0;
    var ageYears:int = 0;
    var ageRmdr:int = 0;

    var diff:Number = now.getTime()-dob.getTime();
    ageDays = diff / 86400000;
    ageYears = Math.floor(ageDays / 365.24);
    ageRmdr = Math.floor( (ageDays - (ageYears*365.24)) / 30.4375 );

    if ( ageRmdr == 12 ) {
        ageRmdr = 11;
    }

    return ageYears + " years " + ageRmdr + " months";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner:

```
int( now.getFullYear() - dob.getFullYear() + (now.getMonth() - dob.getMonth())*.01 + (now.getDate() - dob.getDate())*.0001 );
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a few problems with the top answer here. I used a couple of answers here to cobble together something which was accurate (for me anyway, hope for you too!)

```
private function getYearsOld(dob:Date):uint
{
    var now:Date = new Date();
    var age:Date = new Date(now.getTime() - dob.getTime());
    var yearsOld:uint = age.getFullYear() - 1970;
    return yearsOld;
}
```