# Flex calendar minimum date & age validation

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, calendar, flex4, flash-builder

I'm wiring up a flex registration form, and need to setup a minimum age for registration of a new user of 16 years old. I see the flex calendar component has the option for date ranges and minimum year, but I didn't readily see anything in the attributes for setting a required parameter for selected to be at least 16 years prior to today's date.

What is a good way to setup a calendar validation condition for D.O.B. required to be at least 16 years prior to today?

Answer (score 0):

"flex calendar" - custom component or "DateChooser" ?
**you can calculate dates via pure AS3** like:
get current date -> then set the component range(s) or just compare current date - selected date :)
[What is the best way to calculate Age using Flex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41763/what-is-the-best-way-to-calculate-age-using-flex)