# Age in years from DateTime (Date of birth)

Tags: c#, datetime

#### Duplicate

> [How Can I calculate Someone's Age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

I have a `datetime` variable that represents the date of birth of a user.

How can I get the age in years from this?

**Update**
I want a precise birthday, so 30.45 years or something.

Comment: Dupe : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c

Answer (score 6):

Try the following (assuming the date of birth is stored in `dtDOB`):

```
public int getAgeInYears {
  TimeSpan tsAge = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dtDOB);

  return new DateTime(tsAge.Ticks).Year - 1;
}
```

Comment: This wrong! DateTime.Subtract() returns a Timespan, not a DateTime.

Answer (score 4):

Stolen from the answer to Jeff's question:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
int age = now.Year - bday.Year;
if (now < bday.AddYears(age)) age--;
```

Comment: Cheeky, but worth the points

Answer (score 1):

You can try with (in Vb):

```
    Dim dateOfBirth As Date

    Now.Subtract(dateOfBirth).TotalDays \ 365
```

\ is an Integer division in Vb, I do not know if it has a correspondant in C#.