# How to convert fractional years (say 1.25 years) to number of days

Tags: c#-3.0

I have a table that shows periods like 1 year to 10 years. I want to calculate number of days (approximately 365 days in a year and no need to include leap year). If it was just years, it is easy to calculate days ( like 2 years = 2*365 days). But how can convert for 1.5 years or 1.75 years into days?

what is the efficient way to calculate days if the years are specified in terms of fractional years.

Thanks
nath

Comment: It's similarly easy: `1.25 * 365 = 456.25`...

Comment: Am I missing something?  Isn't 1.5 years just `1.5 * 365 = 547.5`?

Comment: Really? `Math.Round(1.5 * 365)` There are such things as stupid questions.

Comment: Maybe the problem is too simple for me? ...it seems obvious that you multiply `1.5 * 365`. Does that somehow not answer the question?

Comment: My rudimentary maths work it out the same too .. ?

Comment: This is essentially the opposite of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673514/age-in-years-with-decimal-precision-given-a-datetime.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
float year = 1.5;

int days = Math.Round(year * 365);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the original question is trivial, I'll answer the more interesting question where leap years and other date/time oddities are to be considered. Since the exact number of days in a year is dependent on the year in question, the only sensible approach would be to calculate it relative to a given date. The first step would be an `AddYears` overload that accepts `double` values:

```
public static DateTime AddYears(this DateTime dateTime, double years)
{
    int roundedYears = (int) Math.Floor(years);
    var roundedDate = dateTime.AddYears(roundedYears);
    var lastYearSpan = roundedDate.AddYears(1) - roundedDate;
    return roundedDate.AddDays((years % 1) * lastYearSpan.TotalDays);
}
```

Now you can get the number of days that make sense for you, for example:

```
var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
Console.WriteLine((now.AddYears(1.25) - now).TotalDays);
```

Sample tests:

```
public void TestAddYearsDouble()
{
    var date = new DateTime(2000, 1, 15); //middle of the month to keep things simple
    Assert.AreEqual(date.Year + 1, date.AddYears(1.0).Year);
    Assert.AreEqual(date.Month, date.AddYears(1.0).Month);
    Assert.AreEqual(date.Year, date.AddYears(0.0833).Year);
    Assert.AreEqual(date.Month + 1, date.AddYears(0.0833).Month);
    Assert.AreEqual(date.Year + 8, date.AddYears(8.5).Year);
    Assert.AreEqual(date.Month + 6, date.AddYears(8.5).Month);
}
```