# How to display ages instead of dates of birth, in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Get person's age in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819263)

I am very new to Ruby on Rails, and I have just created a small program to store people, using their names, dates of birth (dob), genders, etc. However, when I query the people from the database using `@persons = Persons.find(:all)`, and I try to list them, I'd love to display their age, that is, today - persons.dob, rather than their date of birth proper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails has a couple of Date-Helpers, among them distance_of_time_in_words: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words.

As far as I remember it adds an "about x years", so it might be not useful in your particular situation unless you take a look at the source and adapt it.

Otherwise you can calculate with years directly calling Date.today.year (or dob.year).

Answer (score 7):

```
today = Date.today
d = Date.new(today.year, dob.month, dob.day)
age = d.year - dob.year - (d > today ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: `d < today` will always return true

Comment: how can be birthday's year AFTER today? :)

Comment: @fl00r, check again how d is constructed, d is this year's birthday. I did have a problem with the comparison reversed though

Comment: It fails for dob being on Feb 29. Use an extra check for date 29 Feb. Better change every 29 Feb to 28 Feb.

Answer (score 4):

```
def age(dob)
  today = Date.today
  age = today.year - dob.year
  age -= 1 if dob.strftime("%m%d").to_i > today.strftime("%m%d").to_i
  age
end

dob = Date.new(1976, 4, 10)
age(dob)
#=> 35
dob = Date.new(1976, 5, 10)
age(dob)
#=> 34
```

Comment: this function will be defined in the controller. However, after @persons = Person.find(:all), my @persons variable is already at the view, and I did not want to include this code at my view, thinking it will break the MVC concept !

Comment: You should add it into helper as a helper method

Answer (score 3):

Apologies in advance...I'm still learning Ruby:

```
require 'date'
dob = Date.new(1976, 7, 4)
now = Date.today
age = ((now - dob) / 365.25).to_i
```

I'm guessing there's a better way...?

Comment: Edit: 365 wasn't correct.  But I'm not satisfied with 365.25.  I'm going to upvote Vadim's for that reason.

Answer (score -2):

This code seems to work for me with a few test ages

```
age = ((Date.today - dob).to_i / 365.25).ceil
```

where you define dob as the date object.