# I found a way to calculate the age in rails. Can some one explain this code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Sorry Im new to rails. I just found a way to calculate the age in a model from here : [Get person's age in Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819263/get-persons-age-in-ruby)

The function is this :

```
def age
  now = Time.now.utc
  now.year - birthday.year - (birthday.to_time.change(:year => now.year) > now ? 1 : 0)
end
```

Can some one please explain whats happening in the third line? I can't understand this :

```
(birthday.to_time.change(:year => now.year) > now ? 1 : 0)
```

Comment: looking up the ternary operator (like: `cond ? yes : no`) should clear thing up

Comment: Use http://stackoverflow.com/a/2357790/2503775, not the check-marked one which can't handle leap years..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sentence is only trying to check if the birthday has already passed for the current year. If it has, then

`(birthday.to_time.change(:year => now.year) > now ? 1 : 0)`

will equal to `0`. otherwise `1`. this will be then subtracted like this:

`now.year - birthday.year - 1` or `now.year - birthday.year - 0`

Hope that clarifies your doubt.

Just a suggestion, I would rather use `irb` and break up above code in smaller pieces and see what each part does exactly for myself. This would help me understand stuff better.