# how to get only user total age(like age-17) data in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my age.html.erb

```
<%= f.label :date_of_birth%>
<%= f.date_field :date_of_birth,:order => [:day, :month, :year]%>
```

It shows only user birthyear data (like - 2000),
 
But I want to show only user total age like this (age-17).

Comment: It seems you've missed some code while posting the question, please fix it

Comment: create one method to calculate age `def age(dob)
  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
end`  Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/2357790