# Calculate and display user age in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a `date_field :born_in` for age and i want to display the calculated user age in user profile instead of the regular date format `mm/dd/yyyy`

I found a [method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2357790/11536405) in this answer on how to calculate user's age but i don't know how to implement it in my rails app.

**user_information.rb**

```
class UserInformation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  has_one :gender, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :gender, :allow_destroy => true

  has_one :relationship, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :relationship, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= @user.user_information.try(:born_in) %>
```

Comment: What have you tried? What does your User model look like?

Comment: @moveson i have included my model to my question

Answer (score 1):

Put the method in your model as a property (instance function rather than class function ) then in your form just pop the result into the page. You have shown no code whatsoever so I can not give you a code example to fix your problem but something like this maybe

```
class Person ...
  ...

  def calculated_age
    now = Time.now.utc.to_date
    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
  end
```

Then in your view

```
<%= @person.calculated_age #Or whatever your instance variable name is %>
```

You might also want to add a check that dob is not null and set an appropriate default in the model

This is exactly what models are for. Views should just render the information they are given
Show more code next time and help people to help you.

Comment: I have updated my question and included my nested model to devise users model. i got this error `undefined local variable or method `dob' for #<UserInformation:0x00007feccd3a0d60>`

Comment: @seddka You have supplied no code at all related to your new error. I can't help with no information

Comment: @seddka where did you define dob?

Comment: i got it working, i'll post an answer about it . thank you for your help, appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

before i tried @jamesc solution:

```
def calculated_age
    now = Time.now.utc.to_date
    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
  end
```

but i got an error saying :

`undefined local variable or method dob' for #<UserInformation:0x00007feccd3a0d60>`

That's because dob was not defined in the calculated method .

This is the solution i came up with :

```
def age
    now = Time.current
    dob = self.born_in
    now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
  end
```

And in Users profile `show.html.erb` all i had to do is :

```
<%= @user.user_information.age %>
```