# Two dates within a year of each other

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I got two dates, how do I check if both dates does not exceed over one year?

Short question! :-)

Comment: @OP: do you mean "within a year of each other" or "in the same year?"

Comment: Please be more specific about what exact you want. You could either have the two days be no more than 365 days apart or have both dates in the same year (simple case)

Comment: I thought this was a glory post from a programmer who had dates with two different women in the same calendar year for the first time =/

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
if (Math.Abs((d1 - d2).TotalDays) < 365)
```

---

**Edit:** This should account for leap years better.

```
if ( d1 <= d2 && d1.AddYears(1) >= d2 || d2 < d1 && d2.AddYears(1) > d1)
```

**Update:**
I like @JDunkerley's solution better:

```
if (d1 < d2 ? d2 < d1.AddYears(1) : d1 < d2.AddYears(1))
```

Comment: What if I'd like to compare 1st Jan 2008 and 31st Dec 2008? This expression would be telling me a lie!

Comment: What do you recommend then, pestaa?

Comment: @pestaa: This is true. It's naive regarding leap years. I originally used .TotalYears and then realized TimeSpan doesn't have that.  I'll have something more complete up in a few moments.

Comment: Magic number warning! What about leap year? :)

Comment: Taking leap years into consideration.

Comment: I suggest to simply check whether year % 4 == 0. If so, abs(totaldays) < 366, otherwise it remains 365.

Comment: @pestaa: that's not good enough either.  1900, and 2100 would both fail that.  See my update.

Comment: @pestaa: you could get round that case by:
if (d1 < d2 ? d2 < d1.AddYears(1) : d1 < d2.AddYears(1))

Comment: Is that simple in C#? Thank god there are competent programmers. :) I'm not familiar with this language. Though, this was a simple yet exciting discussion.

Comment: No offense to the original poster, but isn't this answer somewhat flawed by the fact it re-invented the wheel of something that is already implemented in the framework ( System.TimeSpan ) with a roll your own solution, which as it stood initially contained a bug?  Nothing to mention readability.

Comment: The original solution used a TimeSpan.  I agree it's flawed as a result of a mistake admitted earlier, hence the hastily implemented edit that should now look a little better.

Comment: Hey, Joel, this gets kinda confusing. Once you sacrifice readability to achieve flexibility, now you ignore equality? Give it some thought before.

Comment: @pestaa: I don't have an IDE handy and typed the initial answer directly into the browser, expecting there to be a .TotalYears property on timespan.  I immediately realized that mistake, and spend several updates correcting it one bit at a time.  What I came up with isn't as nice as JDunkerley's, but I didn't want to just copy.

Answer (score 2):

I give you a little example:

```
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

 DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds( 75 );

 TimeSpan span = endTime.Subtract ( startTime );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (seconds): " + span.Seconds );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (minutes): " + span.Minutes );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (hours): " + span.Hours );
 Console.WriteLine( "Time Difference (days): " + span.Days );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan ts = Date1.Subtract(Date2);

if(ts.Days > 365)
{
// Over a year.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That depends on the date format.

- If you have two timestamps, you may calculate the difference between them.
- If you have two specific dates in a known format, you simply compare the year attributes as strings.

Answer (score 0):

If they're both in DateTime structures, then you can just subtract the two to get a [Timespan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) structure. The Timespan structure has a [Days](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days.aspx) property which you can look at.

So you'll have something like:

```
if(Math.Abs((date1 - date2).Days) <= 365) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same question as ["how do I calculate someone's age"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c).

Blatantly stealing the answer from there and modifying it for use:

```
public static bool DatesAreWithinOneYear(DateTime date1, DateTime date2)
{
    DateTime startDate = date2 > date1 ? date1 : date2;
    DateTime endDate = date2 > date1 ? date2 : date1;

    int years = endDate.Year - startDate.Year;
    if (endDate < startDate.AddYears(years))
    {
        years--;
    }
    return years < 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If necessary, swap t1 and t2 so that t1 <= t2

```
if(t1.AddYears(1) >= t2) {
    // t1 is within a year of t2
    return true;
} else {
    // t1 is not within a year of t2
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
if (year(date1) == year(date2))
{
   //true
}
else
{
   //false
}
```

Comment: This would answer the question as it is posed in the question title. If you are looking for something that will make sure two dates are within a year span of time, then Joel's or another answer would be more suitable. This just checks if the year is the same.

Comment: Sorry if I misguided my question. Joel's answer did the trick. Thanks for your effort.

Comment: meep: It's alright. Although the slew of downvotes on it AFTER I explicitly stated that another may be more useful is pretty shady. Oh well.