# ruby date subtraction

Tags: ruby, date, datediff

I have a problem with date subtraction in Ruby

```
"2011-03-29".to_date - "2011-03-20".to_date #=> (9/1)
("2011-03-29".to_date - "2011-03-20".to_date).to_i #=> 9
```

Seems it's returning the difference between dates in number of days.

Now my problem is to return number of years, months, days of the date difference

```
ie ("2011-03-29".to_date - "2011-03-20".to_date)
```

should return

```
0 years, 0 month and 9 days
```

Thanks.

Comment: What library or framework are you using that provides the `to_date` method for a string?  Rails?  Something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this link:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words

OR

```
  def time_diff_in_natural_language(from_time, to_time)
    from_time = from_time.to_time if from_time.respond_to?(:to_time)
    to_time = to_time.to_time if to_time.respond_to?(:to_time)
    distance_in_seconds = ((to_time - from_time).abs).round
    components = []

    %w(year month week day).each do |interval|
      # For each interval type, if the amount of time remaining is greater than
      # one unit, calculate how many units fit into the remaining time.
      if distance_in_seconds >= 1.send(interval)
        delta = (distance_in_seconds / 1.send(interval)).floor
        distance_in_seconds -= delta.send(interval)
        components << pluralize(delta, interval)
      end
    end

    components.join(", ")
  end

  time_diff_in_natural_language(Time.now, 2.5.years.ago)
  >> 2 years, 6 months, 2 days
```

Reference: [In Rails, display time between two dates in English](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065320/in-rails-display-time-between-two-dates-in-english)

Comment: Please don't program defensively

Comment: Defensively? Please elaborate.

Comment: I know what it means... Like I have check of to_time method on from time. Right Tass ???

Answer (score 1):

I know it is kinda dirty but have you tried:

```
result = Date.new(0) + ("2011-03-29".to_date - "2011-03-20".to_date)
puts "#{result.year} years, #{result.month - 1} months and #{result.day} days"
```

Comment: I think u missed #{result.month-1}, this is because Date.new(0) takes January as a month.

Comment: You are right. Months start by 1. I have just updated the answer. Tks.