# Calculate years from date

Tags: php, datetime

I'm looking for a function that calculates years from a date in format: 0000-00-00.
Found this function, but it wont work.

```
// Calculate the age from a given birth date
// Example: GetAge("1986-06-18");
function getAge($Birthdate)
{
  // Explode the date into meaningful variables
  list($BirthYear,$BirthMonth,$BirthDay) = explode("-", $Birthdate);
  // Find the differences
  $YearDiff = date("Y") - $BirthYear;
  $MonthDiff = date("m") - $BirthMonth;
  $DayDiff = date("d") - $BirthDay;
  // If the birthday has not occured this year
  if ($DayDiff < 0 || $MonthDiff < 0)
  $YearDiff--;
 }

echo getAge('1990-04-04');
```

outputs nothing :/
i have error reporting on but i dont get any errors

Comment: This function has no `return` line, hence it doesn't output anything. Looks very incomplete.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because the function is not returning anything to print.

As far as algorithms go, how about this:

```
function getAge($then) {
    $then_ts = strtotime($then);
    $then_year = date('Y', $then_ts);
    $age = date('Y') - $then_year;
    if(strtotime('+' . $age . ' years', $then_ts) > time()) $age--;
    return $age;
}
print getAge('1990-04-04'); // 19
print getAge('1990-08-04'); // 18, birthday hasn't happened yet
```

This is the same algorithm (just in PHP) as the accepted answer [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c).

A shorter way of doing it:

```
function getAge($then) {
    $then = date('Ymd', strtotime($then));
    $diff = date('Ymd') - $then;
    return substr($diff, 0, -4);
}
```

Comment: In the second way of doing it, you shouldn't be modifying the input $then. You should store this as a separate variable.

Answer (score 18):

An alternative way to do this is with PHP's [DateTime class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) which is new as of PHP 5.2:

```
$birthdate = new DateTime("1986-06-18");
$today     = new DateTime();
$interval  = $today->diff($birthdate);
echo $interval->format('%y years');
```

[See it in action](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RazGDg)

Comment: Small correction: DateTime::diff() is new as of PHP 5.3

Answer (score 5):

A single line function can work here

```
function calculateAge($dob) {
    return floor((time() - strtotime($dob)) / 31556926);
}
```

To calculate Age

```
 $age = calculateAge('1990-07-10');
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to return $yearDiff, I think.