# Find difference between two dates in PHP or MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

This query does not return the records for january, but it returns records for february.

```
SELECT EventAsstCharged,CustomerName,EventID ,EventName,EventExpectedCharges,EventActuallyCharged,EventUserCharged,date_format(EventDate,'%d-%m-%Y') as EventDate ,EventTime FROM tblevent WHERE Status=1 AND date_format(EventDate,'%d-%m-%Y') between '01-01-2011' AND '20-02-2011' AND EntryUser=2 AND Status=1 ORDER BY EventID DESC
```

How to find the age between two dates using PHP or MySQL?

```
2009-09-24 21:09:36     2010-03-04 13:24:58
```

Comment: many duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1203651/how-do-i-easily-determine-the-age-from-an-birthday-php-closed

Answer (score 6):

```
<?php
$diff = strtotime('2010-03-04 13:24:58') - strtotime('2009-09-24 21:09:36');
echo "Difference is $diff seconds\n";
$days = floor($diff/(3600*24));
echo "Difference is $days days\n";
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also do it at the database level using the [`DATEDIFF()`](http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_datediff_mysql.asp) function.

http://www.w3schools.com/SQl/func_datediff_mysql.asp

Answer (score 3):

You can use [**this excellent function by Added Bytes**](http://www.addedbytes.com/code/php-datediff-function/) to find it, I think.

```
echo datediff('yyyy', '2009-09-24 21:09:36', '2010-03-04 13:24:58);
```

Check out the function parameters for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I found that the easiest way to find the difference between two dates is this one:

```
<?php
    // Get current time, or input time like in $date2
    $date1 = time();

    // Get the timestamp of 2011 July 28
    $date2 = mktime(0,0,0,7,28,2011);
?>
<?php
    $dateDiff = $date2 - $date1;
    $fullDays = floor($dateDiff/(60*60*24));
    echo "$fullDays";
?>
```

Source: http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-date-difference.html

Answer (score 1):

```
function dateDiff($endDate, $beginDate)
{
$date_part1=explode(" ", $beginDate);
$date_part2=explode(" ", $endDate);

$date_parts1=explode("-", $date_part1[0]);
$date_parts2=explode("-", $date_part2[0]);
$start_date=gregoriantojd($date_parts1[0], $date_parts1[1], $date_parts1[2]);
$end_date=gregoriantojd($date_parts2[0], $date_parts2[1], $date_parts2[2]);
return $end_date - $start_date;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed my ticket age using the following MySQL query.

```
DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),SUBSTR(ticket.created,1,10)) AS ticket_age
```