# Calulate Years from two dates in MySql

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find difference between two dates in PHP or MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2622774/find-difference-between-two-dates-in-php-or-mysql)

Bonjour! My question is how do you calculate the number of years between two dates using MySql and Php seperately? I want 2 answers: One for MySql and the other for Php.

Comment: You "want"? SO is not a "code this for me thxbye" website; show what you did so far

Answer (score 0):

MySQL:

```
YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(datecolumn)
```

PHP:

```
$interval = date_diff($datetime1, $datetime2);
echo $interval->y;
```

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50358/what-is-with-people-who-answer-questions-that-are-known-to-be-dupes