# Calculate days remaining to a birthday?

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a DateTime object with a person's birthday. I created this object using the person's year, month and day of birth, in the following way:

```
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

I would like to know how many days are remaining before this person's next birthday. What is the best way to do so in C# (I'm new to the language)?

Comment: @Mitch - sounds so but the full text search did not find a dupe in a few seconds so I thought I'd write the question in an articulate way...

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c

Comment: @Russ - sorry but it's a different question. There are some similarities but it's certainly not the same (best proof is that the answers are different...)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
// birthday is a DateTime containing the birthday

DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime next = new DateTime(today.Year,birthday.Month,birthday.Day);

if (next < today)
    next = next.AddYears(1);

int numDays = (next - today).Days;
```

This trivial algorithm fails if the birthday is Feb 29th. This is the alternative (which is essentially the same as the answer by Seb Nilsson:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime next = birthday.AddYears(today.Year - birthday.Year);

if (next < today)
    next = next.AddYears(1);

int numDays = (next - today).Days;
```

Comment: TotalDays returns a double : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx

Comment: +1 This is close to the "manual" way I'm using right now, I thought maybe there's a neat C# trick to simplify it.

Comment: +1, i thought he used DateTime.Now which includes the current time.

Comment: This will fail if the birthday is February 29 and the current year is not a leap year

Comment: @JesperLarsen-Ledet Indeed, I will correct my answer to handle this edge case

Comment: This is nice and elegant, but the handling for Feb 29th has one additional edge case that is missed. Consider the following conditions: birthday is Feb 29 and is past for the current year, the current year is not a leap year but the next year is. With the current logic above, the calculated "Days" will be one less than it should be as you'll be adding 1 year to Feb 28 even though it's for a leap year. See my answer for the slight one line tweak.

Comment: @JStuart You're right that it is one day off for the edge case you described, but the solution you proposed crashes in most cases when the birthday is a leap day

Comment: @PhilippeLeybaert Good catch - I was too myopic in my testing. I've updated my answer below with the additional check necessary to handle the scenario you described.

Answer (score 7):

Using today's year and the birthday's month and day **will not work with leap-years**.

After a little bit of testing, this is what I get to work:

```
private static int GetDaysUntilBirthday(DateTime birthday) {
    var nextBirthday = birthday.AddYears(DateTime.Today.Year - birthday.Year);
    if(nextBirthday < DateTime.Today) {
        nextBirthday = nextBirthday.AddYears(1);
    }
    return (nextBirthday - DateTime.Today).Days;
}
```

Tested with 29th February on a leap-year and also when the birthday is the same day.

Comment: This is the only methods that works 100%. The reason is that it uses `AddYears` which never fails for the ultimo dates of February.

Answer (score 2):

This is based off of Philippe Leybaert's answer above, but handles one additional edge case that I don't see accounted for in any of the previous answers.

The edge case I'm addressing is when the birthday is on a leap day, the birthday is in the past for the current year, and the **current year isn't a leap year but the next year is**.

The current answer provided will result in one fewer day as it sets "next" to Feb 28 of the current year and then adds a year making the date Feb 28 of a leap year (which isn't correct). Changing one line handles this edge case.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
DateTime next = birthday.AddYears(today.Year - birthday.Year);

if (next < today)
{
    if (!DateTime.IsLeapYear(next.Year + 1))
        next = next.AddYears(1);
    else
        next = new DateTime(next.Year + 1, birthday.Month, birthday.Day);
}

int numDays = (next - today).Days;
```

Update: Edited per Philippe's pointing out that my code had a rather sizable flaw.

Comment: This code crashes when today's year is any year except a year before a leap year and when the birthday is Feb 29th.

Comment: This should (now) be accepted answer as it correctly handles all dates including leap years

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime dt1 = DateTime.Parse("09/08/2012");
            DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString());
            int days = (dt2 - dt1).Days;
            Console.WriteLine(days);

            double month = (dt2 - dt1).Days / 30;
            Console.WriteLine(month);
            double year = (dt2 - dt1).Days / 365;
            Console.WriteLine(year);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this method

```
private int GetDaysBeforeBirthday(DateTime birthdate)
{
    DateTime nextBday = new DateTime(DateTime.Now.Year, birthdate.Month, birthdate.Day);
    if (DateTime.Today > nextBday)
        nextBday = nextBday.AddYears(1);
    return (nextBday - DateTime.Today).Days;
}
```

just pass your birthdate and it will return the remaining days before your next birthday

Comment: How is this different from Philippe's answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
        DateTime Variable = DateTime.Now;
        int NumOfDaysTillNextMonth = 0;
        while (Variable < Comparer) //Comparer is just a target datetime
        {
            Variable = Variable.AddDays(1);
            NumOfDaysTillNextMonth++;
        }
```

Had to do this just now for a program. It's simple enough as opposed to the other methods if all you need is an integer of days left.