# Calculate no of days remaining

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to **calculate no of days remaining** for particular day from today onwards. How to calculate difference between 2 dates in C#??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170257/calculate-days-remaining-to-a-birthday

Comment: `DateDiff("d",Day(Date()),#28/10/2013#)` returns 41547 because today is the 28th day of the month so `Day(Date())` returns 28 and `CDate(28)` is `1900-01-27`. Therefore, `DateDiff()` is counting the number of days between `1900-01-27` and `2013-10-28`. If you get rid of the `Day()` part then things should work better.

Answer (score 3):

(Note: This answer was written when the question was worded very differently)

Assuming your dates are `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`:

```
TimeSpan delta = date1 - date2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
TimeSpan GetDelta(DateTime d1, DateTime d2)
{
    return (d1 - d2).TotalDays;
}
```