# C# 3.0 How can I get readonly property value?

Tags: c#-3.0

In C# 3.0, I'm doing the code below to declare a DateTime property and a int age property that is read only.

```
public class MyClass{
    public DateTime dateOfBirth{ get; set; }
    public int age { get; }

    public MyClass(){}

    public int CalculateAge(){}
}
```

But how can I get this updated age (that it's read only) when someone enters his date of birth in a form, for example?

Comment: I didn't even know that it was possible to declare an auto-implemented property without a set-block (private would be fine) since you can never initialize the property.

Comment: It's not possible to do this - the compiler will complain, precisely for the reason you give.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't store the age, instead calculate it when get of the age property is executed:

`public int Age { get { return 100; } }`

But instead of returning 100, you do the calculation.

Comment: I've tried to do that but in my CalculateAge method it says that Age cannot be assigned because it's read only.

Comment: He said 'don't store the age...'

Answer (score 8):

You need to implement the "age" property so it works off the dateOfBirth property:

```
public int age { 
    get {
         return (DateTime.Now - this.dateOfBirth).Days / 365;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah - well, I was just trying to show the technique, not the specifics.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an auto readonly property for this. You'll have to implement the property. You might also consider using a TimeSpan instead of int, since it will be more versatile.

```
public TimeSpan Age 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return DateTime.Now - this.dateOfBirth; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having `Age` be an automatic property, implement an age calculator.

```
public class MyClass {
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public int Age { 
        get {
            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            int age = now.Year - DateOfBirth.Year;
            if(now < DateOfBirth.AddYears(age)) age--;
            return age;
        }
    }
}
```

You should probably refactor the above calculation out into a method, but the above demonstrates the salient point.

Answer (score 1):

As Svinto says, calculate the age and return that in the get method of your Age property. [See How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c) on SO for ideas on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a property which only you can assign, but which anyone can read:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Age { get; private set; }
}
```

Then your class can assign `Age`, but other classes can only read it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your code to calculate the age in your age property.

For example:

```
public int Age
{
     get
     {
          return (age code here);
     }
}
```

Comment: that won't compile.  You can't implicitly convert a timespan to an int.

Comment: @Reed Copsey - there is no timespan in dark's code; it just says 'age code here' in the return. the actual code for computing the integer age value goes in the parantheses.

Answer (score 0):

Why not change your implementation a little:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public DateTime DateOfBirth {get; set;}
    public int Age
    {
        get
        {
            return this.CalculateAge();
        }
    }
}
```