# how can i calculate age by datetimepicker

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate someone’s age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age)

How can i calculate age using datetimepicker in c#?

Comment: One of the very first questions on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c

Answer (score 7):

Strictly speaking,

```
TimeSpan age = DateTime.Now - dateTimePicker.Value;
```

However, figuring out someone's "age" is only slightly more complicated.

```
int years = DateTime.Now.Year - dateTimePicker.Value.Year;

if(dateTimePicker.Value.AddYears(years) > DateTime.Now) years--;
```

Because years vary in length you'll have to do this rather than relying on a structure like the `TimeSpan` that represents a specific amount of time (the same is true for figuring out how many "months" are between two dates, since months vary in length from 28-31 days).

The last line of code is there to account for the person's birthday not yet taking place this year.

Comment: int years = DateTime.Now.Year - dateTimePicker.Value.Year;

if(dateTimePicker.Value.AddYears(years) > DateTime.Now) years--;


>> why is that when i added that code in datetimepicker.... the age doesnt appear?

Comment: @malou17: Adding that code isn't going to make the age appear, it just calculates it and puts it in a variable for you. How do you want it to appear?

Comment: Pretty sleek logic, tthe datepicker's ValueChanged is where you can place the code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the DateTimePicker is called dtpBirthday:

```
int age = DateTime.Now.Year - dtpBirthday.Value.Year - (DateTime.Now.DayOfYear < dtpBirthday.Value.DayOfYear ? 1 : 0);
```

Comment: This would not account for a birthday taking place later in the current month. For example, if my birthday happened to be February 24, 1901, then this code would say I'm already 109 when I'm only a spry 108.