# Calculate Year, Month and Day between two Dates in C#

Tags: c#, date, date-difference

I want exact Year, Month and Day elapsed between two dates.

```
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(1974, 8, 15);

DateTime endDate = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
```

I wish to find Number of Years, Months and Days elapsed between the above two days using C#?

> My Expected Output
>
> Years: **68** Months: **10** Days: **23**

I referred one of the post, in that they explained about only days [Calculate difference between two dates (number of days)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607336/calculate-difference-between-two-dates-number-of-days)

But I need all three - Year, Month and Day. Kindly assist me how to calculate...

**Explanation for Duplicate**:
Already a question with same logic posted in [Calculate Years, Months, weeks and Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260372/calculate-years-months-weeks-and-days), the answer provided in that question is too lengthy and **in my question I asked only Year, Month and Date not Week**. **The Concept is same but the logic is different for calculating days comparing to that question**, Here I got the answer in a very simplified manner. **I satisfied in my answer**.

**Exact Duplicate:**

Original Question: [How to get difference between two dates in Year/Month/Week/Day?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083955/how-to-get-difference-between-two-dates-in-year-month-week-day) (**Asked 7 Years ago**)

Your Marked Question: [Calculate Years, Months, weeks and Days](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260372/calculate-years-months-weeks-and-days)  (**Asked 5 Years ago**)

Comment: How do you get 68 years from 1974 to 2016?

Comment: Actual difference is 2016 - 1947 = 69, but hear we are calculating the month and day so, I misused the year by one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Interesting Question:

The Solution is

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime zeroTime = new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
    DateTime olddate = new DateTime(1947, 8,15);
    olddate.Dump();
    DateTime curdate = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();
    curdate.Dump();

    TimeSpan span = curdate - olddate;

    // because we start at year 1 for the Gregorian 
    // calendar, we must subtract a year here.

    int years = (zeroTime + span).Year - 1;
    int months = (zeroTime + span).Month - 1;
    int days = (zeroTime + span).Day;

    years.Dump();
    months.Dump();
    days.Dump();
}
```

Comment: The "solution" is very popular one, but it is clearly wrong as number of years/month depend on exact dates and definition of what OP is looking for. I.e. how long 30 days in month -  1 month 2 days or  1/1 or 1/0 or 0/30?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov The doubt is absolutely right. you test with **`DateTime olddate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-29);`**. The result is Year: 0, Month: 0, Days: 30. It will work fine in all scenarios.

Comment: If my date starts with a given date then can it is necessary to subtract 1 from the year?

Comment: This is off by 1 day. Should be Day - 1.

Comment: @JeromeViveiros. I agree, but this is a matter of definition (whether or not you start counting at 0 or 1).

Comment: B.Balamanigandan: Alexei is right. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68200511/385995) for an extended explanation. I still think this code is the best approximation we can get, however.

Comment: @MikeFuchs... To be fair, I'm using the code. It works but I don't see why the definition for day should be different to years or months. Honestly it doesn't make much of a difference as time goes by. Using it to show the time diff for overcoming addiction... I'm 8 years odd clean from meth and around six months since I gave up smoking... The days only matter right at the beginning.

Comment: @JeromeViveiros. Agreed, use cases which use this kind of output would rarely care too much about the exact number of days. Well done on overcoming addiction.