# age should be calculated based on date of birth in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I m new in asp.net

I want when user select date of birth then automatically calculate their age and fill up the age text box and I performing one logic but somewhere My logic is wrong?

code:

default.aspx

```
<form>
            <label for="date"><b>Date Of Birth:</b></label>
            <asp:Calendar  ID="txtdate" placeholder="Select Your Date Of Birth" runat="server" OnSelectionChanged="txtdate_SelectionChanged"></asp:Calendar>


            <label for="age"><b>Age:</b></label>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtage" runat="server" placeholder="Age"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
```

default.aspx.cs

```
        protected void txtdate_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DateTime birthdate=txtdate.SelectedDate.Date;  //select date from calender

            int age = DateTime.Now.Year - birthdate.Year;

            txtage.Text = age.ToString();
        }

        protected void age_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
```

**when I select the date of birth from calender(1/12/2017) In the watch window then display the 3 year 
but I want to display 2 years 4 months 24 days**

watch window:

[image]

which place I need to change my logic?

Comment: Talk us through what you think `int age = DateTime.Now.Year - birthdate.Year;` does?

Comment: @mjwills which place change the code? because int, float give the whole number

Comment: https://forums.asp.net/t/1289294.aspx?TimeSpan+Years+and+Months

Comment: This questuion is already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38215171/calculate-year-month-and-day-between-two-dates-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
var age = DateTime.Now - birthdate;
```

Instead of:

```
int age = DateTime.Now.Year - birthdate.Year;
```

Comment: when I select 28/12/2018 then display the age this type 575.15:20:13.7173816

Comment: here I m missing something  ```txtage.Text = age.ToString();``` I m writing the tostring that is the reason the date is not properly shown? what can I do here

Answer (score 1):

```
    DateTime Birth = txtdate.SelectedDate.Date;
    DateTime Today = DateTime.Now;


    TimeSpan Span = Today - Birth;


    DateTime Age = DateTime.MinValue + Span;


    // note: MinValue is 1/1/1 so we have to subtract...
    int Years = Age.Year - 1;
    int Months = Age.Month - 1;
    int Days = Age.Day - 1;
    txtage.Text = Years.ToString() + " Years, " + Months.ToString() + " Months, " + Days.ToString() + " Days";
```

Comment: can u change this line  ```DateTime Birth = txtdate.SelectedDate.Date;``` accordingly your code is working fine

Comment: and one thing I notice many online age calculators is displaying the wrong date that is the reason testing for multi-time