# Operate between datetimepickers

Tags: c#, datetimepicker, operations

I am trying to get the difference between two datetimepickers.

For example:
Between X date and Y date, have been past X days, Y months and Z years.

So, if I'd put in the first datetimepicker my birth date and in the second the day of today, I would my exact age, for example: "20 days, 3 months and 26 years".

I tried a few codes, but the results are not correct.

Thanks in advance.

The code is:

```
string age = "Tu age es de:\n";
age = age + ((Math.Abs(DateTime.Today.Day - dtpage.Value.Day)).ToString()) + " days, ";
age = age + ((Math.Abs(DateTime.Today.Month - dtpage.Value.Month)).ToString()) + " months";
age = age + " y " + ((Math.Abs(DateTime.Today.Year - dtpage.Value.Year)).ToString()) + " years";
MessageBox.Show(age);
```

EDIT: Solved in [C# calculate accurate age](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054715/c-sharp-calculate-accurate-age)

Comment: please put some of those **few codes** here

Comment: You have many different solutions here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177002/how-to-subtract-a-datetime-from-another-datetime

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Please show the code if this answer is not sufficient, but if you're talking about `DateTime` objects, just use the `Subtract` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
DateTime birthdayDate = DateTime.Now; //get the date from datetimepicker
var dateTimeResult = DateTime.Now.Subtract(birthdayDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `Datediff` will accomplish this.

Edit - here:

```
string diff = DateAndTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Second, DateTimePicker1.Value, DateTimePicker2.Value);
Interaction.MsgBox(diff);
```

Now just format the seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have to write a couple of your own lines of code, which is not too hard if you look at your classes.  Here is a simple example, you may need to check for a negative month value and if so add 12 to it, since you would be carrying a year over.

```
        DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime d2 = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-28938923);

        int years = d.Year - d2.Year;
        int months = d.Month - d2.Month;
        int days = d.Day - d2.Day;

        if (days < 0)
        { 
            // borrow a month
            months--;
            // use your brain power to pick the correct month.  I have not thought this step out.
            days += DateTime.DaysInMonth(d.Month);  
        }
        if (months < 0)
        { 
            // borrow a year
            years--;
            months += 12;
        }
```

Comment: Solved in:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054715/c-sharp-calculate-accurate-age