# Calculate the difference between two dates and get the value in years?

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate someone’s age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

I want to calculate basically the age of employees -  So we have DOB for each employee, So on 
the C# Side I want to do something like this -

```
int age=Convert.Int32(DateTime.Now-DOB);
```

I can use days and manipulate then get the age...but I wanted to know if there something I can use directly to get the number of years.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Do you want calculate the age in years for an employee? Then you can use this snippet (from [Calculate age in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
int age = now.Year - bday.Year;
if (bday > now.AddYears(-age)) age--;
```

If not, then please specify. I'm having a hard time understanding what you want.

Comment: Ya this is what i want to do...sorry for not phrasing it well..

Comment: Hi, why do you decrement the age in the 3rd line?

Comment: @WTFZane Because if the date that year is greater than the date in the current year, then they aren't that age yet. e.g. DOB = 30/5/2000. Today = 30/4/2010. age = 10. Then adjust to 9 as they are only 9 years old.

Comment: Note this fails, by 1 day, for anyone born on 29th Feb as their birthday in a non-leap year is 1 March (i.e. "the day after 28 Feb") in certain countries (e.g. UK). That is because `AddYears()` returns 28 Feb for any non-leap year (if the date of birth input is a valid 29 Feb date). An ideal solution would include the country as a parameter :)

Comment: Do this to take into consider leap years also
DateTime.Today.Year - DateOfBirth.Year +(DateTime.Today.DayOfYear < DateOfBirth.DayOfYear?-1:0)

Answer (score 20):

Subtracting two `DateTime` gives you a [`TimeSpan`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) back.  Unfortunately, the largest unit it gives you back is Days.

While not exact, you **can** estimate it, like this:

```
int days = (DateTime.Today - DOB).Days;

//assume 365.25 days per year
decimal years = days / 365.25m;
```

Edit: Whoops, TotalDays is a double, Days is an int.

Comment: Nice answer!I wonder about the division with 365.25. Why is not just 365.0. I found that in other topics too and wonder if you can enlighten me.

Comment: .25 is due to leap years

Comment: I also fixed it to use Days instead of TotalDays.  TotalDays is a double, not an int.  Since we don't care about partial days anyway...

Comment: this isn't entirely accurate.  We don't always have a leap year every four years.

Comment: @matt-dot-net Since the only time that will matter is for people over 115 years old, I'm sure it will work in most cases.

Answer (score 13):

On [this](http://www.geekpedia.com/code81_Calculate-age-using-Csharp.html) site they have:

```
   public static int CalculateAge(DateTime BirthDate)
   {
        int YearsPassed = DateTime.Now.Year - BirthDate.Year;
        // Are we before the birth date this year? If so subtract one year from the mix
        if (DateTime.Now.Month < BirthDate.Month || (DateTime.Now.Month == BirthDate.Month && DateTime.Now.Day < BirthDate.Day))
        {
            YearsPassed--;
        }
        return YearsPassed;
  }
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Nice And Simple

Comment: Note, that you can use DateTime.Now.Month <= BirthDate.Month instead of DateTime.Now.Month < BirthDate.Month || (DateTime.Now.Month == BirthDate.Month.

Answer (score 4):

```
    private static Int32 CalculateAge(DateTime DOB)
    {
        DateTime temp = DOB;
        Int32 age = 0;
        while ((temp = temp.AddYears(1)) < DateTime.Now)
            age++;
        return age;
    }
```

Comment: dividing by 365 doesn't handle leap years and actually dividing by 365.25 doesn't actually handle leap years accurately either.

Comment: This is actually closer, to a working solution, but it is out by a day. Should be `<= DateTime.Now` in your specific example. Born 28/1/1980 -> 28/1/1981 = 0 in your example

Answer (score 0):

Math.Round(DateTime.Now.Subtract(DOB).TotalDays/365.0)

As pointed out, this won't work.  You'd have to do this:

```
(Int32)Math.Round((span.TotalDays - (span.TotalDays % 365.0)) / 365.0);
```

and at that point the other solution is less complex and continues to be accurate over larger spans.

Edit 2, how about:

```
Math.Floor(DateTime.Now.Subtract(DOB).TotalDays/365.0)
```

Christ I suck at basic math these days...

Comment: This will only work for shorter spans, obviously, but if nobody's going to be more than 150 years old...

Comment: Yup, it doesn't work.  Timespan needs a "TotalYears" property :-)

Comment: Sorry to flog a dead horse here but this also doesn't take into account leap years, so it'll return incorrect results in a time span of as little as 1 year.

Answer (score -4):

```
(DateTime.Now - DOB).TotalDays/365
```

Subtracting a DateTime struct from another DateTime struct will give you a TimeSpan struct which has the property TotalDays... then just divide by 365

Comment: Not every year has 365 days...