# How do I calculate someone's Age?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate someone’s age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

How do I calculate someone's age in C#, if I have their Birthdate and today's date?

Comment: would u mind giving me the link to that question discussion page?

Answer (score 0):

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan_members(v=VS.71).aspx

Timespan contains members for Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, Milliseconds, and Ticks.  How accurate do you want it to be?

Comment: But what I want is Year, Month and day