# Calculating difference between two DateTime objects in C#

Tags: c#

I have two DateTime objects in C#, say birthDateTime and curDateTime.

Now, I want to calculate the year difference bewteen current datetime and someone's birthday. I want to do something like

```
int years = curDateTime- birthDateTime;
//If years difference is greater than 5 years, do something.
  if(years > 5)
    ....
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you are trying to calculate a person's age in the way people usually respond when asked for their age.

See [Calculate age in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c) for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The subtraction operator will result in a TimeSpan struct.  However, the concept of "years" does not apply to timespans, since the number of days in a year is not constant.

```
TimeSpan span = curDateTime - birthDateTime;
if (span.TotalDays > (365.26 * 5)) { ... }
```

If you want anything more precise than this, you will have to inspect the Year/Month/Day of your DateTime structs manually.

Comment: Note that you should not use this solution if you want to compute "age" in the way people usually state a person's age.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddYears` method and check the condition if the `Year` property.

```
var d3 = d1.AddYears(-d2.Year);

if ((d1.Year - d3.Year) > 5)
{
    var ok = true;
}
```

You will need to handle invalid years, e.g. `2010 - 2010` will cause an exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (birthDateTime.AddYears(5) < curDateTime)
{
    // difference is greater than 5 years, do something...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime someDate = DateTime.Parse("02/12/1979");
int diff = DateTime.Now.Year - someDate.Year;
```

This is it, no exceptions or anything...