# age calculation

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

I am trying to create a form where a client's date of birth is entered and his age is displayed automatically in txtAge:

```
 private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     dtpDob.Value = DateTime.Today.Date;
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
 }  

 private void dtpDOB_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
 {
     System.DateTime dob = default(System.DateTime);
     dob = dtpDob.Value.Date;
     txtAge.Text = DateTime.DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, dob, DateTime.Today.Date);
 }
```

But I get these errors:

> 'System.DateTime' does not contain a definition for 'DateDiff'.
>   The name 'DateInterval' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static int GetAge(DateTime birthDate)
        {
            return (int)Math.Floor((DateTime.Now - birthDate).TotalDays / 365.242199);
        }
```

Comment: doing this as an extension method would be a nice way to do it too :)

Comment: That doesn't account for leap years, so it will show the wrong age when the birthday is close to todays date.

Comment: @Guffa true, added that part. Nonetheless this question should be closed due to duplicate

Comment: That's better, but it's still an approximation and shows the wrong age in some cases (Yes, I have tested this).

Comment: @Guffa yaeh I know. Tested it myself. But didn't feel like putting too much time into a question when the answer is already in SO

Comment: @Oskar Kjellin: So why did you post an answer at all, if you are not bothered to post code that works properly?

Comment: @Guffa At first I was dedicated to make a good answer. But then I found the dupe and just wanted this to close

Answer (score 1):

You would need to import the VB libraries to use `DateDiff`, and it's not part of the `DateTime` structure.

Although, using `DateDiff` does not calculate the age correctly, it only gives you the difference between the years of the dates, not the difference between the dates in years.

A simple way to calculate the age is to increase the birth date by a year until you pass the todays date:

```
private void dtpDOB_Leave(object sender, System.EventArgs e) {
  System.DateTime dob = default(System.DateTime);
  dob = dtpDob.Value.Date;

  int age = -1;
  DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
  while (dob <= today) {
    age++;
    dob = dob.AddYears(1);
  }
  txtAge.Text = age.ToString();
}
```

Note: This calculation takes leap years into account, so you will get the actual age, not an approximation.

Answer (score 0):

try this for the age in days:

```
txtAgeInDays.Text = (DateTime.Now - dob).ToString ("dddddd");
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.tostring.aspx