# Which unit do you subtract from JavaScript / MongoDB Date object?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, date, datetime

Refering to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18212982/date-sub-interval-equivalent-in-mongodb, I need to subtract N days from a Date object. As MongoDB uses Javascript datatypes, my question is:

On subtracting X from Date(), is X the number of seconds?
Or Minutes? Or Microseconds?

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#date

Comment: possible duplicate of [Query Mongodb on month, day, year... of a datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136652/query-mongodb-on-month-day-year-of-a-datetime)

Comment: It's not a duplicate and it doesn't tell me which unit X is

Comment: The docs in the link I added as well as the other question.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=milliseconds+in+day&oq=milliseconds+in+day

Comment: Thank you for your effort and helpful research, Sir.

Comment: I actually was confused by this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187824/finding-date-by-subtracting-x-number-of-days-from-a-particular-date-in-javascrip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

X is miliseconds. [its not microseconds]

Comment: A microsecond isn't a millisecond.

Comment: So `Date() - (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)` represents 24 hours of range correct?

Comment: yes correct . It will substract one day from the current Date() . check out this for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14135856/calculating-number-of-days-between-dates