# getting value from jDateChooser and saving to MS sql DB

Tags: java, sql-server, swing, jdatechooser

I have two jDateChooser on my dialog , I want to save to MS-SQL DB having issue with that data types. Any idea how to fix this issue ! I can only do this when i convert data type to nvarchar in DB and convert the value to string which returns from jDateChooser.

[image]

//  I can save in this way but I it doesn't use jDateChooser;

```
   java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
   java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

// I cant save the date with jDateChooser

```
    java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser3.getDate());
```

// Only Way I found

```
  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

  String sd = dateFormat.format(jDateChooser3.getDate());

  obj.setStartDate(sd);
```

//

Comment: Where is this `JDateChooser` class coming from? Which library and package?

Comment: it is this one http://toedter.com/software/

Comment: Please post MCVE (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). By the mean time please check the return type of JdateChooser.getDate() if it is java.util.Date then try java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser3.getDate()getTime());

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Judging from the code you posted it looks like `jDateChooser3.getDate()` returns a `java.util.Date` instance while the `java.sql.Date(millis)` constructor expects the date/time as a `long` milliseconds value.

Use this code and it will work:

```
java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(jDateChooser3.getDate().getTime());
```

Since it comes from a date chooser component, invalid input most likely results in `null` returned date, so you might want to also check on that:

```
java.util.Date d = jDateChooser3.getDate();
if (d == null) {
    System.out.println("No date specified!");
} else {
    java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(d.getTime());
    // Do something with sqldate
}
```

Comment: how about calculating  days  between these two dates

Comment: Days between two dates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103064/java-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Comment: hey man it saves the database like this it doesn't show the time 2014-05-12 00:00:00.000

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with having no time? Doesn't the date come from a date chooser which doesn't specify the time?

Comment: I cant save the time to database ! that is the problem how to combine all together

Comment: You have to use the SQL type `java.sql.Timestamp` instead of `java.sql.Date` if you also want to save time too.

Comment: yeah it is working now but one more problem the format of the date  2014-05-01 16:46:45.123 i want in this way dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

Right click on jDateChooser. Go to the Properties and dateFormatString. Set this format: dd-MM-yyyy.

Answer (score 0):

```
      Date keyword = jDateChooserattendance.getDate();
      java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(keyword.getTime());
```