# how can insert date value from jDateChooser to sql database

Tags: java, sql, date

1- a me tried in this way

```
 String sql = "insert into transport(s_id,transport_date)" +
            " values (  + jTextField2.getText()+","
                     + ((JTextField)jDateChooser1.getDateEditor().getUiComponent()).getText() +")"; 

pst=con .prepareStatement(sql2);
             pst.executeUpdate();
```

2- and this way

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  String date=sdf.format(jDateChooser1.getDate());

String sql = "insert into transport(s_id,transport_date)" +
            " values (  + jTextField2.getText()+","
                     +  date +")";
```

in #run
examble today choose : 2021-5-27
will insert 1989 !

Comment: How about using a [PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) and a setDate method?

Comment: 1) The first code snippet, at least, does not look like it would even compile. For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) While debugging, factor out all the GUI parts and simply try and insert a date into the DB (from a console app.). The [tag:swing] tag has been removed.

Comment: try to check this link on how to use jdatechooser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23564363/getting-value-from-jdatechooser-and-saving-to-ms-sql-db

Answer (score 0):

Using `+` to place data in an SQL statement is **EXTREMELY DANGEROUS.**  Aside from cross-site scripting, it is one of the greatest sources of hacks and vulnerabilities in software!  For a more detailed explanation, search the web for “SQL injection”.

Do not, under any circumstances, place data in an SQL statement using concatenation (using `+` or StringBuilder or StringBuffer or Formatter or any other similar string construction mechanism).

The only safe way to add user-supplied data to a database statement is with PreparedStatement.  The String argument you pass to `prepareStatement` must not have any data in it.  Instead, you place question marks (`?`) in the String, to act as placeholders for data;  then you use the various set* methods of PreparedStatement to replace each question mark with data.  This allows the PreparedStatement to guarantee safety.

```
Instant instant = jDateChooser1.getDate().toInstant();
LocalDate date = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

String sql = "insert into transport(s_id,transport_date) values (?, ?)";
pst = con.prepareStatement(sql);
pst.setString(1, jTextField2.getText());
pst.setObject(2, date);
pst.executeUpdate();
```