# Output error while calculating difference

Tags: java, date, time

I have four dates and I want to calculate the days difference between dates. My program is as below.

```
    Date d1 = new Date("11/28/14 23:59:58");
    Date d2 = new Date("11/29/14 00:00:02");
    Date d3 = new Date("11/29/14 23:59:58");
    Date d4 = new Date("11/30/14 00:00:02");

    final long DAY_IN_MILLIS = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    int diff1 = (int) ((d2.getTime()- d1.getTime())/DAY_IN_MILLIS);
    int diff2 = (int) ((d3.getTime()- d1.getTime())/DAY_IN_MILLIS);
    int diff3 = (int) ((d4.getTime()- d1.getTime())/DAY_IN_MILLIS);



    System.out.println(diff1);
    System.out.println(diff2);
    System.out.println(diff3);
```

**I want diff1=1, diff2=1 & diff3=2**.

But my **output is diff1=0, diff2=1, diff2=1**.

Comment: `Date(String)` is deprecated, just btw.

Comment: Comparing dates like that is a really bad idea too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java, Calculate the number of days between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103064/java-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using the modern Java 8 time API:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yy HH:mm:ss");
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse("11/28/14 23:59:58", formatter);
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse("11/29/14 00:00:02", formatter);
LocalDate d3 = LocalDate.parse("11/29/14 23:59:58", formatter);
LocalDate d4 = LocalDate.parse("11/30/14 00:00:02", formatter);
int diff1 = d1.until(d2).getDays();
int diff2 = d1.until(d3).getDays();
int diff3 = d1.until(d4).getDays();
System.out.println(diff1);
System.out.println(diff2);
System.out.println(diff3);
```

Comment: If I'm having Java 7 installed. So in that case, will it work ?

Comment: Nope. If you cannot use Java 8, consider using Joda Time API as @aviad suggests.

Answer (score 1):

There's a 4 second different between d2 and d1, so 0 days makes sense for `diff1`.

Between d3 and d1 there 1 day exactly, which is what you got in `diff2`.

Between d4 and d1 there's a little over 1 day (1 day and 4 seconds), so 1 makes sense in `diff3` when using int division.

To make it clearer, here are the results when using floating point division :

```
4.6296296296296294E-5
1.0
1.0000462962962964
```

Comment: Thanks Eran.... but as per my requirement is that whenever there is date change, it should give me diffrence as 1. Even if diffrence is 1 second.

so please guide me how to do this.

Comment: @ChandraBhan What if both dates have the same day (for example d3 and d2). Do you expect to get 0 or 1?

Comment: if both dates are same then I would expect 0.

Answer (score 1):

it is only 4 sec diference between d2 and d1. Hence, the num of full days between them is 0 and not 1 as you would expect because the diff is treated as the diff between 2 timestamps.
I strongly recommend you to use [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), which is a easier API than Date. You can then use:

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(d2, d1).getDays();
```

Comment: Thanks ! But as per my requirement, Even if there is difference of 1 second between 2 dates, it should return 1.
Its like d1 is monday and d2 is tuesday....so difference should return 1.

Comment: then work with the timestamps :) good luck with your requirements