# Need number of days based on difference of two dates

Tags: java, apache-poi, jxl

Scenario:

> My result = Report generation date - Visited date

Example:

> Report generation date is : 20/07/2016

If Visited date is 19/07/2016 - result is 0, if Visited date is 18/07/2016 - result is 1, if Visited date is 17/07/2016 - result is 2, etc.

Comment: and what is stopping you? please, don't just copy paste your assignment here. at the very least, show us what you've tried, and what (didn't) work

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103064/java-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try This**

```
 public static void main(String []args) {
    System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    System.out.println(new Date());
    Map<TimeUnit,Long> result = computeDiff(
            new Date("7/20/2016"),
        new Date("8/20/2016")
    );
    System.out.println(result);
 }

public static Map<TimeUnit,Long> computeDiff(Date date1, Date date2) {

    long diffInMillies = date2.getTime() - date1.getTime();
    List<TimeUnit> units = new ArrayList<TimeUnit>(EnumSet.allOf(TimeUnit.class));
    Collections.reverse(units);

    Map<TimeUnit,Long> result = new LinkedHashMap<TimeUnit,Long>();
    long milliesRest = diffInMillies;
    for ( TimeUnit unit : units ) {
        long diff = unit.convert(milliesRest,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        long diffInMilliesForUnit = unit.toMillis(diff);
        milliesRest = milliesRest - diffInMilliesForUnit;
        result.put(unit,diff);
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the code..... out put is look like.....                                   {DAYS=1, HOURS=0, MINUTES=0, SECONDS=0, MILLISECONDS=0, MICROSECONDS=0, NANOSECONDS=0}    . But i want only days value... like 1.. so pls suggest me/ give the code.

Comment: add break statment in for loop.so it will return only days value.

Comment: giving out put like {DAYS=7}... But i want only... 7.. how to get this?

Comment: public class Main {
 
     public static void main(String []args) {                 
     long diffInMillies = new Date("7/20/2016").getTime() - new Date("7/19/2016").getTime();     
     List<TimeUnit> units = new ArrayList<TimeUnit>(EnumSet.allOf(TimeUnit.class));    
       Collections.reverse(units);       
       long milliesRest = diffInMillies;       
       long diff = units.get(0).convert(milliesRest,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);               
        System.out.println(diff);
     } 
}