# How to get number of days between two XMLGregorianCalendar Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala, is it possible to get number of days between XMLGregorianCalendar? I cannot find any methods in this class that gets the range of two dates. If not how are you guys doing it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java, Calculate the number of days between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7103064/java-calculate-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates)

Answer (score 0):

Ah I guess not I just went with this instead and it works fine:

```
val range:Long = (toDate.toGregorianCalendar.getTimeInMillis - fromDate.toGregorianCalendar.getTimeInMillis) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)
```