# Displaying total duration using Timespan

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datetime, timespan

I need help to display something like this. If you recognize, this our membership duration of Stack Overflow account.

```
member for  2 years, 3 months
```

I need a slight modification in the same. My conditions and display format are as follows:

```
  Conditions              Display Format
1. Below 7 days  ->       Days (5 days)
2. 7 -30 days    ->       Weeks, days   ( 2 Weeks, 3 Days) in case of 17 days.
3. 30 - 365      ->       Months, Weeks, Days (4Months, 2Weeks, 2Days) in case of 136 days
3. 365 or grter  ->       Years, Months only (2years, 3 Months)

What I did:
```

I am using Timespan to get the date difference. But I am not satisfied with my output. I have a member whose registration's going to 2 months old  after 2-3 days, but still its showing 1 month ago. Here is my code:

```
 TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now - Convert.ToDateTime(company.RegistrationDate);

                 if (ts.Days > 365)
                    membersince.InnerText = string.Format("{0} years", (ts.Days / 365));
                else if (ts.Days < 30)
                    membersince.InnerText = string.Format("{0} days", ts.Days);
                     else if(ts.Days > 30)
                    membersince.InnerText = string.Format("{0} months", (ts.Days/30));
```

Comment: Have you gone through it with a debugger?

Comment: In your question, it is given that "I have a member whose registration's going to 2 months old after 2-3 days, but still its showing 1 month ago." As it is not yet 2 months, shouldn't the output of 1 month correct?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9594583/birthday-age-calculation-but-also-for-number-of-months-and-days/9594788#9594788

Comment: Do you intend to have some rounding off. Foe example: if the number of days is > 55, consider the month as 2 instead of 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **DateDiff** class of the [Time Period Library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/168662/Time-Period-Library-for-NET) library:

```
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
public void DateDiffSample()
{
  DateTime date1 = new DateTime( 2009, 11, 8, 7, 13, 59 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date1: {0}", date1 );
  // > Date1: 08.11.2009 07:13:59
  DateTime date2 = new DateTime( 2011, 3, 20, 19, 55, 28 );
  Console.WriteLine( "Date2: {0}", date2 );
  // > Date2: 20.03.2011 19:55:28

  DateDiff dateDiff = new DateDiff( date1, date2 );

  // elapsed
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedYears: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedYears );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedYears: 1
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedMonths: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedMonths );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedMonths: 4
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedDays: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedDays );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedDays: 12
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedHours: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedHours );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedHours: 12
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedMinutes: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedMinutes );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedMinutes: 41
  Console.WriteLine( "DateDiff.ElapsedSeconds: {0}", dateDiff.ElapsedSeconds );
  // > DateDiff.ElapsedSeconds: 29
} // DateDiffSample
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is this a problem? If one's age is 57 days, then `57 / 30 == 1`. If you are expecting to get `2` out of this, then you should

1) make sure the result of your division is double (simply divide by `30.0` instead of `30`). The reason is that `int / int` is also an `int`.

Simple test:
`(57 / 30).GetType().Name == Int32`
`(57 / 30.0).GetType().Name == Double`

Also `(int)1.9 == 1`.

2) `Math.Round()` the result. This would be actual mathematical rounding, as opposed to just dropping everything after decimal point.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `TotalDays` which will give you double (and is more 'politically' correct as `Days` is just the component, though in your case is similar), and `Math.Round()` as already suggested by @Ilia to the 'nearest'.

```
Math.Round(ts.TotalDays);
```

...or

```
String.Format("{0:0.##}", ts.TotalDays);
```

...which should give you like `1.7 months` (as I recall from my head or test for your winning format)

**It's more a logical and user-interface problem**, how to 'present' to the user.

EDIT: use just `TotalDays` to format as `1.7` - or use Math.Round to get a round month

Comment: @IliaG rightly so :) - I'm just too asleep still, had a 10 edits on this small thing :)

Comment: @IliaG Feel free to edit your answer (e.g. with totaldays) to merge this and let's kick out this one - as both are the same and I don't see much about going on about this.

Answer (score 0):

```
static public string calculateAge(DateTime birthDate, DateTime now)
{
  birthDate = birthDate.Date;
  now = now.Date;

  var days = now.Day - birthDate.Day;
  if (days < 0)
  {
    var newNow = now.AddMonths(-1);
    days += (int)(now - newNow).TotalDays;
    now = newNow;
  }
  var weeks = days / 7;
  days = days - weeks * 7;
  var months = now.Month - birthDate.Month;
  if (months < 0)
  {
    months += 12;
    now = now.AddYears(-1);
  }
  var years = now.Year - birthDate.Year;

  if (years > 0)
  {
    if (months > 0)
      return string.Format("{0} Years, {1} Months", years, months);
    else
      return string.Format("{0} Years", years);
  }
  if (months > 0)
  {
    var builder = new StringBuilder();
    builder.AppendFormat("{0} Months", months);
    if (weeks > 0)
      builder.AppendFormat(", {0} Weeks", weeks);
    if (days > 0)
      builder.AppendFormat(", {0} Days", days);
    return builder.ToString();
  }
  if (weeks > 0)
  {
    if (days > 0)
      return string.Format("{0} Weeks, {1} Days", weeks, days);
    return string.Format("{0} Weeks", weeks);
  }

  return string.Format("{0} Days", days);
}
```