# Calculate age from date in textbox in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calculating age from birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/calculating-age-from-birthday)

How do you calculate age in years, taking input from TextBox in the format `dd/MM/yyyy`?

e.g.

> input: txtDOB.Text    20/02/1989 (String format)
>   output: txtAge.Text   23

Comment: Please view this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/c-calculating-age-from-birthday

Comment: I checked it. everything there is assuming the input is in DateTime format,  I am stuck at conversion from textbox to DateTime in the format dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: You can use Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") or DateTime.TryParseExact(TextBox1.Text, 
        "dd/MM/yyyy", 
        null, 
        System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None)

Comment: Hey man, we need your opinion. How will you use any approach below? From medical perspective my approach is incorrect, from users perspective - 50\50. I think if you need precise calculation you should use Matten's approach and play with the ratio. Also I would suggest you to show months along with years to avoid confusion from user pov. You see fit

Comment: The obvious answer is that you increase in age by a year on your birthday... at least, that's how I think most people think birthdays work. :) That does mean that if you're born on a leap day you must wait until 1st March for your birthday! It also means that if you are born on 1st March, then you still celebrate your birthday on 1st March during a leap year - you don't celebrate it on Feb 29th.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `Substract` method of `DateTime` ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ysw4sby.aspx)) and then use the `Days` property to determine the actual age:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime givenDate = DateTime.Parse(input);

int days = now.Subtract(givenDate).Days
int age = Math.Floor(days / 365.24219)
```

Comment: Ignoring years where the number of days isn't 365

Comment: Downvoted because it fails for some inputs.

Comment: @Matthew Watson - Could you please give me an example?

Comment: Sure: DOB = 1964-03-16, TODAY = 2013-03-16. Age should be 49, but your code gives 48.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Ok agree, adjusted on base of the astronomic year.

Comment: I'm not sure that usage of magic like '365.24219' is good solutions.

Comment: It's not magic, it's a constant, known as the astronomic or tropican year. Wikipedia: "Some exceptions to this rule are required since the duration of a solar year is *slightly less* than 365.25 days"

Comment: @Madman in general I'd totally agree with you, magic numbers are no good; but in this case I would use this as input, because it is the current mean solar year *and* it has a great advantage -- returning the right age until you're 36500 years old (based on the way you're calculating the "right" age) :-)

Comment: @Matten Man, I think finally you'll win in spite of magic ;) Until calendar will not changed your approach will work, so I give You my point.

Comment: Such an easy question and no nice answer to go :-)

Comment: Uhm, why not just `new DateTime( DateTime.Now.Subtract( givenDate ).Ticks ).Year` ?

Comment: Hate to say this, but the amended code *still* doesn't work. It doesn't account for leap years properly, so the following is wrong: DOB = 1963-03-01, NOW = 2016-02-29, AGE = 53 (should be 52)

Answer (score 0):

As already noted in a comment, the correct answer is here: [Calculate age in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/c-calculating-age-from-birthday)

You just need to get the birthday as a DateTime:

```
DateTime bday = DateTime.ParseExact("20/02/1989", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: 1/1/2012 - 12/30/2010 = 2, but actual age is 1.

Comment: One of the answers in the quoted thread is correct, but some of them are wrong. You have to find the right one. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
TimeSpan TS = DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1989, 02, 20);
double Years = TS.TotalDays / 365.25;  // 365 1/4 days per year
```

Comment: This will fail to give the right answer in many circumstances.

Comment: Also, `365.25` is an incorrect value. Leap years are *not* precisely every four years. Years ending in `00` are not leap years unless their hundreds/thousands/etc are also divisible by 4. So, 1900 was not a leap year, but 2000 was.

Answer (score 0):

The following will work once you have parsed the birth date into a DateTime:

```
static int AgeInYears(DateTime birthday, DateTime today)
{
    return ((today.Year - birthday.Year) * 372 + (today.Month - birthday.Month) * 31 + (today.Day - birthday.Day)) / 372;
}
```

Parse the date like so:

```
DateTime dob = DateTime.ParseExact("20/02/1989", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

And a sample program:

```
using System;

namespace Demo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DateTime dob = new DateTime(2010, 12, 30);
            DateTime today = DateTime.Now;

            int age = AgeInYears(dob, today);

            Console.WriteLine(age); // Prints "1"
        }

        static int AgeInYears(DateTime birthday, DateTime today)
        {
            return ((today.Year - birthday.Year) * 372 + (today.Month - birthday.Month) * 31 + (today.Day - birthday.Day)) / 372;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It has been well-tested and gives the correct answer for all inputs. It's pointless to downvote something without giving a reason.

Comment: This doesn't work. Try with the sample value: `12/30/2010` for the date of birth and todays date for `today`. It returns `2011`... -1

Comment: No, it correctly returns 1. Why not actually try it? It's definitely correct, and it absolutely certainly works with 2010-12-31 for DOB and 2012-07-30 for today.

Comment: I did... It gives the result `2011`.

Comment: It really doesn't... How are you calculating it? I've added a sample program to the OP. Please compile and run it. You WILL see that the result is 1.

Comment: You're assuming that the datetime is always in that format...

Comment: "You're assuming that the datetime is always in that format": What are you talking about? What format? I'm using DateTime - it HAS NO FORMAT!

Comment: The date of birth? It will be coming from the user through a textbox so won't necessarily be in the format of YYYY/MM/dd...

Comment: My code is not parsing the string since that has already been solved in other comments. My code just calculates the age in years using DateTime objects. The format is therefore irrelevant. The code does work. You clearly haven't actually tried it.

Comment: Read the OP's comments: `I checked it. everything there is assuming the input is in DateTime format, I am stuck at conversion from textbox to DateTime in the format dd/mm/yyyy`. This answer doesn't meet the criteria.

Comment: I've now added the parsing code to my original reply. The parsing code had already been given though - I was just adding the code to actually calculate the age, since all the other posted code was wrong. Notwithstanding the parsing part, the algorithm I posted is definitely correct.

Comment: What's the 372 magic number about?

Comment: More details here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharplanguage/thread/ba4a98af-aab3-4c59-bdee-611334e502f2, but it's the number of days that there would be in a year if all months had 31 days.

Answer (score -1):

This answer isn't the most efficient as it uses a loop, but it doesn't rely on using 365.25 magic numbers either.

A function to return the whole number of years from a `datetime` to today:

```
public static int CalcYears(DateTime fromDate)
    {
        int years = 0;
        DateTime toDate = DateTime.Now;
        while (toDate.AddYears(-1) >= fromDate)
        {
            years++;
            toDate = toDate.AddYears(-1);
        }
        return years;
    }
```

Usage:

```
int age = CalcYears(DateTime.ParseExact(txtDateOfBirth.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

Comment: That doesn't work... The loop always exits immediately so that it always returns 0 if fromDate is more than 1 year before toDate.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - thanks I converted the code from VB but didn't test it before posting - should now work.

Answer (score -2):

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("20/02/1989", "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var age = (DateTime.Today.Year - date.Year);
Console.WriteLine(age);
```

Comment: If you are born at newyear than you are not 1 year old the next day.

Comment: Born: 12/31/1989, Today: 1/1/1990. 1990-1989 = 1

Comment: OK. Did you see the Person with 0 years old ? I agree that formally your example is correct, but from user perspective I think it is not.

Comment: Ok. Born 12/31/1989, Today 1/1/2012. Calculated age is 23, actual age is 22.

Comment: Matten is correct: This code is very definitely wrong.

Comment: Well, I think we need topic starter's opinion, what solutions fit his needs and then make corrections to the answer

Comment: Without using the current date, the error that @Matten pointed out is always going to happen in some form or another. One should instead measure the elapsed time between the DoB and today, then calculate the years from there.

Comment: @MatthewWatson - thanks. i completely missed that.
can u suggest a way, with similar code, so that if the age is 22 yrs 6 mnths, the output is 22. but if it is 22 yrs 7 mnths, the output is 23.
Otherwise the code works fine with me

Comment: You could use the code I posted in my answer (see the AgeInYears() function) - it always gives the right answer (We use it in our production code, and it's been extensively tested. I didn't write it myself though, I got it from a programming forum.)

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
string[] AgeVal=textbox.text.split('/');
string Year=AgeVal[2].tostring();
string CurrentYear= DateTime.Now.Date.Year.ToString();
int Age=Convert.ToInt16((Current))-Convert.ToInt16((Year));
```

Subtract the two values and get your age.

Comment: What is the CommonClass?