# Progressbars in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, progress-bar

I'm developing a tool which does the following operations:

- Download a zip file from a repository
- Extract the zip file.
- Run 5-6 exe/bat files from the extracted contents as separate `Process`.

I need to show a progress bar with approximate percentage completions for these operations. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: @Downvoter: What's unclear/not usefull here?

Comment: Exactly the point that @AdiLester is making, you are just asking a solution, while If I google wpf progress bar, one of the results is WPF toolkit BusyIndicator.

Comment: You're probably getting downvoted because you're not showing any of your own research and/or attempts at solutions.

Comment: The best way it would be is to download a file, show the download progress on the `ProgressBar`, extract the archive and then to run some exe/bat files.

Comment: @J.Steen: Ok. Might be. But I hope the same rule applies to all questions, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c, where the same behavior can be seen.

Comment: @Sandeep It is, however, a question asked and answered by the same person in an effort to give people solutions without needing to ask the same question again. =)

Comment: @Rikkos: Do the BusyIndicator show percentage completions?

Comment: I don't get the downvotes While he could've been more specific about the problem he is facing, it is fairly a straight question and he's merely asking for a recommended approach, not asking "CAN I HAZ TEH CODEZ". Just because he hasn't shown any source code doesn't mean a guidance cannot be provided.

Comment: @Sandeep As far as the documentation goes, you can set the value of the progress bar. Take a look [Here](http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=BusyIndicator)

Answer (score 4):

What do you use to realize each point? Which libraries?

- If you use some external, compiled libraries, you can catch the output and parse it:

  ```
  var proc = new Process {
      StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
          FileName = "program.exe",
          Arguments = "command line arguments to your executable",
          UseShellExecute = false,
          RedirectStandardOutput = true,
          CreateNoWindow = true
      }
  };
  ```

And start the process:

```
proc.Start();
while (!proc.StandardOutput.EndOfStream) {
    string line = proc.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    // parse your output
}
```

- When you download a file, you can use just a simple pattern:

> bytes_already_downloaded/bytes_total * 100 = download_progress_in_%

- If you use some classes (you have source code), you can create a callback action:

  ```
  public void DoSomethingMethod(Action<int> progressCallback)
  {
      while(true)
      {
          // do something here
          // return the progress
          int progress = stuff_done / stuff_total * 100;
          progressCallback(progress);
      }
  }
  ```

And how to use it?

```
MyClass.DoSomethingMethod(delegate(int i) { progressBar.Progress = i; });
```

Or just:

```
MyClass.DoSomethingMethod(i => progressBar.Progress = i);
```

If you mean something else, you can specify it in the comment. I will try to answer:)

Comment: I can't correctly format `DoSomethingMethod`, something works bad;P nvm

Comment: You simply need to indent one more level. =)