# How to accurately get difference between two DateTime object in "Years" [Closed, use NodaTime]

Tags: c#

How to accurately get difference(in years) between two `DateTime` objects in "Years"?

`DateTime.Subtract()` gives difference in `TimeSpan` and the maximum denomination is Days.

So, if I would want to get accurately, the difference between Today and a day in 1988(say 29th March 1988), is there an "easier" way to get the accurate age of this person?

What I've tried is:

```
DateTime March291988 = DateTime.Parse("29/03/1988");
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(March291988);
int years = (ts.Days/365);
```

More importantly, the question is: How to convert from TimeSpan to DateTime.

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Does what you have posted do the job?

Comment: I want DateTime.Now.Subtract() in DateTime instead of TimeSpan(or convert from TimeSpan to DateTime) @Jon

Comment: @Aniket: That doesn't answer my question. Also, "X years" is not a `DateTime`, it only makes sense to have the result as a `TimeSpan`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age

Comment: Re: duplicate: wow. Question 9!

Comment: @Jon I didnot want to use a TimeSpan.. the posted code gives the correct result

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm biased, but I'd use [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com):

```
var date1 = new LocalDate(1988, 3, 29);
var date2 = new LocalDate(2013, 1, 23); // See note below
var years = Period.Between(date1, date2, PeriodUnits.Years).Years;
```

Basically the BCL doesn't provide a hugely easy way of working with things like this - you really *don't* want a `TimeSpan`, because it's not anchored to a specific start/end point. You can subtract one `Year` value from another and then adjust if it does the wrong thing, but it's a bit icky.

Now in your original code, you used `DateTime.Now`. In Noda Time, we treat a clock as a dependency, with `SystemClock.Instance` being the normal production implementation. An `IClock` doesn't know about time zones - it just knows the current instant in time - so you have to say which time zone you're interested in. For example:

```
var today = clock.Now.InZone(zone).LocalDateTime.Date;
```

I know this seems long-winded, but it's isolating all the different conversions to make it all more explicit. (I may introduce a `Date` property on `ZoneDateTime` to reduce this slightly.)

Comment: NodaTime is cool.. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I didnot want to use TimeSpan in any way possible.

Comment: is there a way to convert TimeSpan to DateTime? or convert DateTime to LocalDate()?

Comment: @Aniket: You can't convert from `TimeSpan` to `DateTime`, no. But you can use `LocalDateTime.FromDateTime` and then use the `Date` property to get a `LocalDate`.

Comment: Ah cool, just one more question, where can I get more docs on C#(5.0) and its libraries(the standard ones)(maybe as a PDF, so I can get a print).. also thanks for the link to NodaTime actually.. I will be using that in my current project.

Comment: @Aniket: That's a pretty unrelated question... MSDN is the best place for library stuff, and the C# 5 spec should be installed in your Visual Studio directory. (I don't think it's available for download yet.)

Comment: I am amazed at the amount of detailed knowledge you have in .NET and programming in general. And watched your talk on "Pushing the boundaries of the language" where you said read the specs to understand how and why of a language.. then do the evil thing of pushing the language to its limits.

Comment: And searched hard and long for the documents on the net(in PDF format). I couldn't find them

Comment: @Aniket: Well I doubt that you'll find much framework documentation in PDF format - it's all just online web pages. The spec is in Word, but you could presumably print to PDF.

Comment: Yes, I found the Spec and I was going through it. I just wanted to have an indepth understanding of the language. Is it possible to gain deep understanding of the language through that same spec in VS/Specifications/1033/ folder?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you find the spec, so long as you're using the version you want to learn about :) The one installed with Visual Studio 2012 will be for C# 5, so I'd use that.

Comment: That's awesome :-) thanks for everything Jon - btw, here is one more to that "Chuck Norris" style jokes: "If Jon Skeet were the Producer in Producer-Consumer problem, the Consumer would never run out of whatever he was consuming"

Comment: @JonSkeet please consider moving/copying/recreating this answer about "use NodaTime to compute difference between dates" to very popular duplicate .

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Will do.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get the age in years:

```
static int AgeInYears(DateTime birthday, DateTime today)
{
    return ((today.Year - birthday.Year) * 372 + (today.Month - birthday.Month) * 31 + (today.Day - birthday.Day)) / 372;
}
```

This accounts for leap years, and will increment the age exactly on their birthday.

Comment: This is not what I wanted. I could think of an algorithm like this too, but I wanted to convert the TimeSpan to DateTime

Comment: Ah sorry, I thought you wanted the difference in whole years.

Comment: which is why I mentioned 'accurately' :-P.. +1 though.. good answer.

Comment: Yes, I took "accurately" to mean "gives the correct number of years for all dates". Some algorithms give the wrong number of years around the anniversaries of the datum.