# Automatic Age Calculation ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, count, calculated-field, automatic-updates

Please see the figure below. I want to automatically count the age of the user by inputting their birthday information. See the figure below for more explanation.
[image]

Here's my full code of register.aspx page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<%@ Page Language="C#" Debug ="true" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Data.OleDb" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head runat="server">
<script type="text/c#" runat="server">


  protected void AccessDataSource1_Inserted(object sender, SqlDataSourceStatusEventArgs e)
  {
      string query = "SELECT @@IDENTITY";
      OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, (OleDbConnection)e.Command.Connection);
      int newid = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();  
      Response.Redirect("registerpage2.aspx?id=" + newid);
  }
</script>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Register</title>
<style type="text/css">
.style1 {
    background-image: url('images/REGISTER.jpg');
}
#form2 {
    height: 75px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    table-layout: auto;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0px;
}
.style2 {
    border-width: 0px;
}
.style4 {
    text-align: right;
}
.style5 {
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.style6 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function FP_swapImgRestore() {//v1.0
 var doc=document,i; if(doc.$imgSwaps) { for(i=0;i<doc.$imgSwaps.length;i++) {
  var elm=doc.$imgSwaps[i]; if(elm) { elm.src=elm.$src; elm.$src=null; } } 
  doc.$imgSwaps=null; }
}

function FP_swapImg() {//v1.0
 var doc=document,args=arguments,elm,n; doc.$imgSwaps=new Array(); for(n=2; n<args.length;
 n+=2) { elm=FP_getObjectByID(args[n]); if(elm) { doc.$imgSwaps[doc.$imgSwaps.length]=elm;
 elm.$src=elm.src; elm.src=args[n+1]; } }
}

function FP_preloadImgs() {//v1.0
 var d=document,a=arguments; if(!d.FP_imgs) d.FP_imgs=new Array();
 for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) { d.FP_imgs[i]=new Image; d.FP_imgs[i].src=a[i]; }
}

function FP_getObjectByID(id,o) {//v1.0
 var c,el,els,f,m,n; if(!o)o=document; if(o.getElementById) el=o.getElementById(id);
 else if(o.layers) c=o.layers; else if(o.all) el=o.all[id]; if(el) return el;
 if(o.id==id || o.name==id) return o; if(o.childNodes) c=o.childNodes; if(c)
 for(n=0; n<c.length; n++) { el=FP_getObjectByID(id,c[n]); if(el) return el; }
 f=o.forms; if(f) for(n=0; n<f.length; n++) { els=f[n].elements;
 for(m=0; m<els.length; m++){ el=FP_getObjectByID(id,els[n]); if(el) return el; } }
 return null;
}
// -->
</script>
</head>

<body onload="FP_preloadImgs(/*url*/'images/hover home.jpg',/*url*/'images/hover LCUP.jpg',/*url*/'images/hover help.jpg')" style="margin: 0; background-color: #808080">

<form id="InputForm" runat="server" class="style5" style="height: 646px">

<table style="width: 941px; height: 646px" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" class="style1">
    <!-- MSTableType="layout" -->
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
        <a href="default.htm">
        <img alt="" src="images/normal%20home.jpg" width="72" height="54" id="img1" onmouseout="FP_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="FP_swapImg(1,1,/*id*/'img1',/*url*/'images/hover home.jpg')" class="style2" /></a></td>
        <td valign="top">
        &nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top">
        &nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top">
        <a href="http://www.lcup.edu.ph">
        <img alt="" src="images/normal%20lcup.jpg" width="47" height="54" id="img4" onmouseout="FP_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="FP_swapImg(1,1,/*id*/'img4',/*url*/'images/hover LCUP.jpg')" /></a></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top" colspan="2" style="height: 58px; ">
        <img alt="" src="images/normal%20help.jpg" width="77" height="54" id="img5" onmouseout="FP_swapImgRestore()" onmouseover="FP_swapImg(1,1,/*id*/'img5',/*url*/'images/hover help.jpg')" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 95px">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top">
    <asp:AccessDataSource runat="server" ID="AccessDataSource1" DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [PendingRecords] WHERE [ID] = ?" InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [PendingRecords] ([Username], [Password], [FirstName], [LastName], [MiddleName], [Address], [Age], [Gender], [ContactNumber], [PlateNumber], [Color], [Brand], [LiscensedNumber], [SSSNumber], [TIN], [Type], [Model], [BirthDay], [BirthMonth], [BirthYear]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [PendingRecords] SET [Username] = ?, [Password] = ?, [FirstName] = ?, [LastName] = ?, [MiddleName] = ?, [Address] = ?, [Age] = ?, [Gender] = ?, [ContactNumber] = ?, [PlateNumber] = ?, [Color] = ?, [Brand] = ?, [LiscensedNumber] = ?, [SSSNumber] = ?, [TIN] = ?, [Type] = ?, [Model] = ?, [BirthDay] = ?, [BirthMonth] = ?, [BirthYear] = ? WHERE [ID] = ?" DataFile="_private/records.mdb" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [PendingRecords]" OnInserted="AccessDataSource1_Inserted">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Age" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="SSSNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="TIN" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Model" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="BirthDay" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="BirthMonth" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="BirthYear" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:parameter Name="Username" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Password" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="FirstName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="LastName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="MiddleName" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Address" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Age" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Gender" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="ContactNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="PlateNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Color" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Brand" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="LiscensedNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="SSSNumber" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="TIN" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Type" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="Model" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="BirthDay" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="BirthMonth" Type="String" />
            <asp:parameter Name="BirthYear" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:AccessDataSource>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 33px;">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 76px">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td valign="top" colspan="8">
    <asp:FormView runat="server" id="InputForm1" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DataKeyNames="ID" DefaultMode="Insert" Width="832px">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            ID:
            <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" id="IDLabel1" />
            <br />
            Username:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Username") %>' runat="server" id="UsernameTextBox" />
            <br />
            Password:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Password") %>' runat="server" id="PasswordTextBox" />
            <br />
            FirstName:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' runat="server" id="FirstNameTextBox" />
            <br />
            LastName:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' runat="server" id="LastNameTextBox" />
            <br />
            MiddleName:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("MiddleName") %>' runat="server" id="MiddleNameTextBox" />
            <br />
            Address:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' runat="server" id="AddressTextBox" />
            <br />
            Birhtday:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Birhtday") %>' runat="server" id="BirhtdayTextBox" />
            <br />
            ContactNumber:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("ContactNumber") %>' runat="server" id="ContactNumberTextBox" />
            <br />
            PlateNumber:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("PlateNumber") %>' runat="server" id="PlateNumberTextBox" />
            <br />
            Color:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Color") %>' runat="server" id="ColorTextBox" />
            <br />
            Brand:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("Brand") %>' runat="server" id="BrandTextBox" />
            <br />
            LiscensedNumber:
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("LiscensedNumber") %>' runat="server" id="LiscensedNumberTextBox" />
            <br />
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Update" CommandName="Update" id="UpdateButton" CausesValidation="True" />
            &nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" id="UpdateCancelButton" CausesValidation="False" />
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <div class="style6">
                <table style="width: 100%; text-align: right" align="right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="form2" class="style2">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: right; height: 25px; width: 111px;">
                        Firstname:</td>
                        <td style="width: 280px; height: 25px;">
                        <div>
                            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' runat="server" id="FName" Width="267px" Height="10px" ValidationGroup="reg">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left; width: 3px;">
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left;">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="!" id="RequiredFieldValidator1" style="text-align: left" ControlToValidate="FName" ValidationGroup="reg" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 111px; height: 25px;">Lastname:</td>
                        <td style="width: 280px; height: 25px;">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox6" Width="267px" Height="10px" Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' ValidationGroup="reg">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left; width: 3px;">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left;">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="!" id="RequiredFieldValidator2" ControlToValidate="TextBox6" ValidationGroup="reg" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 111px; height: 25px;">Middle Name:</td>
                        <td style="width: 280px; height: 25px;">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox7" Width="267px" Height="10px" Text='<%# Bind("MiddleName") %>' ValidationGroup="reg">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left; width: 3px;">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left;">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="!" id="RequiredFieldValidator3" ControlToValidate="TextBox7" ValidationGroup="reg" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 111px; height: 25px;">Address:</td>
                        <td style="width: 280px; height: 25px;">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox8" Width="267px" Height="10px" Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' ValidationGroup="reg">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left; width: 3px;">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left;">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="!" id="RequiredFieldValidator4" style="text-align: left" ControlToValidate="TextBox8" ValidationGroup="reg" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 111px; height: 25px;">Contact No.:</td>
                        <td style="width: 280px; height: 25px;">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox9" Width="267px" Height="10px" Text='<%# Bind("ContactNumber") %>' ValidationGroup="reg">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left; width: 3px;">
                        &nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left;">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="!" id="RequiredFieldValidator5" ControlToValidate="TextBox9" ValidationGroup="reg" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="! 09######### - Must be 11 digits." id="RegularExpressionValidator1" ControlToValidate="TextBox9" ValidationExpression="^\d{11}$" ValidationGroup="reg" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td style="height: 25px; text-align: left;">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 111px">Gender:</td>
                        <td style="width: 280px" class="style4">
                        <asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" id="RadioButtonList1" Width="200px" ValidationGroup="reg" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatLayout="Flow" Height="20px" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Gender") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem>Male</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>Female</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: left; width: 3px;">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="!" id="RequiredFieldValidator12" ValidationGroup="reg" ControlToValidate="RadioButtonList1" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 111px">Birthday:</td>
                        <td style="width: 280px" class="style4">
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList2" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("BirthMonth") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem>Month</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>January</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>February</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>March</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>April</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>May</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>June</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>July</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>August</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>September</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>October</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>November</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>December</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList3" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("BirthDay") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem>Day</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>3</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>4</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>5</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>6</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>7</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>8</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>9</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>10</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>11</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>12</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>13</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>14</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>15</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>16</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>17</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>18</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>19</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>20</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>21</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>22</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>23</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>24</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>25</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>26</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>27</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>28</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>29</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>30</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>31</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList4" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("BirthYear") %>'>
                            <asp:ListItem>Year</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1920</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1921</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1922</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1923</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1924</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1925</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1926</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1927</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1928</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1929</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1930</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1931</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1932</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1933</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1933</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1934</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1935</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1936</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1937</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1938</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1939</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1940</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1941</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1942</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1943</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1944</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1945</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1946</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1947</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1948">1948</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1949</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1950</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1951</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1952</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1953</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1954</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1955</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1956</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1957</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1958</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1959</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1960</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1961</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1962</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1963</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1964</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1965</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1966</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1967</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1968</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1969</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1970</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1971</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1972</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1973</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1974</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1975</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1976</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1977</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1978</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1979</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1980</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1981</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1982</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1983</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1984</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1985</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1986</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1987</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1988</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1989</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1990</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1991</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1992</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1993</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1994</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1995</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1996</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1997</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1998</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>1999</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2000</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2001</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2002</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2003</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2004</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2005</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2006</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2007</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2008</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2009</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2010</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2011</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2012</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem>2013</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: left; width: 3px;">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="! Month" id="RequiredFieldValidator13" ControlToValidate="DropDownList2" ValidationGroup="reg" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="Month" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="! Day" id="RequiredFieldValidator14" ValidationGroup="reg" ControlToValidate="DropDownList3" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="Day" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="! Year" id="RequiredFieldValidator15" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="DropDownList4" ValidationGroup="reg" InitialValue="Year" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: left">&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 111px">Age:</td>
                        <td style="width: 280px" class="style4">
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" id="TextBox1" Text='<%# Bind("Age") %>' Height="10px" Width="70px">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: left; width: 3px;">&nbsp;</td>
                        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; ">
                        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="! Please specify your age." id="RequiredFieldValidator16" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="reg" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                        <asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="! Invalid Age" id="RegularExpressionValidator2" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="\d{2}" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="reg" ForeColor="#FF9933">
                        </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; ">
                        <asp:ImageButton CommandName="Insert" runat="server" id="Submit" alt="" src="images/normalnext.jpg" width="146px" height="43px" style="float: right" ValidationGroup="reg" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
                <br />
            </div>
            <br />
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <table style="width: 100%; text-align: right" align="right" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="form3" class="style2">
                <tr>
                    <td style="text-align: right; height: 25px;">Firstname:</td>
                    <td style="width: 280px; height: 25px;">
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("FirstName") %>' runat="server" id="FirstNameLabel" />
                    </div>
                    </td>
                    <td style="height: 25px">&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 108px; height: 25px;">Lastname:</td>
                    <td style="width: 280px; height: 25px;">
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("LastName") %>' runat="server" id="LastNameLabel" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="height: 25px"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 108px; height: 25px;">Middle Name:</td>
                    <td style="width: 280px; height: 25px;">
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("MiddleName") %>' runat="server" id="MiddleNameLabel" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="height: 25px"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 108px; height: 25px;">Address:</td>
                    <td style="width: 280px; height: 25px;">
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("Address") %>' runat="server" id="AddressLabel" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="height: 25px"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 108px; height: 25px;">Contact No.:</td>
                    <td style="width: 280px; height: 25px;">
                    <asp:Label Text='<%# Bind("ContactNumber") %>' runat="server" id="ContactNumberLabel" />
                    </td>
                    <td style="height: 25px"></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 108px">Gender:</td>
                    <td style="width: 280px"><asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="Female0" Text="Female" /><asp:RadioButton runat="server" id="Male0" Text="Male" />
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 108px">Birthday</td>
                    <td style="width: 280px"><asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList2" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("BirthMonth") %>'/><asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList3" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("BirthDay") %>'/>   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" id="DropDownList4" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("BirthYear") %>'/>          </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>


            </table>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            &nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" id="EditButton" CausesValidation="False" />
            &nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" id="DeleteButton" CausesValidation="False" />
            &nbsp;
            <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="New" CommandName="New" id="NewButton" CausesValidation="False" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
        </td>
        <td style="height: 296px">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 72px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 72px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 72px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 230px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 51px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 29px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 300px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 37px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="width: 60px">&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="height: 88px; width: 18px">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</form>

        </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate: **[How do I calculate someone's age](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1404/500725)**

Comment: @SivaCharan could you please edit my code above? then i can copy then try it to run? please

Answer (score 1):

Try this code I found in google, it should do the trick:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
int age = now.Year - bday.Year;

if (now < bday.AddYears(age)) 
    age--;
```

Comment: where I'm gonna put this code? i'm using FormView in my registration page

Comment: Oh sorry, I didn't know FormView doesn't use code behind. Inside your <script type="text/c#" runat="server"> script you can create a function and name it like GetAge() or whatever you like.

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript

```
function getAge(dateString) { //parameter date from form, should look like "03/21/1986"
    var today = new Date();
    var birthDate = new Date(dateString);
    var age = today.getFullYear() - birthDate.getFullYear();
    var m = today.getMonth() - birthDate.getMonth();
    if (m < 0 || (m === 0 && today.getDate() < birthDate.getDate())) {
        age--;
    }
    return age;
}
```

Comment: Compiler Error Message: CS1001: Identifier expected...in this line function getAge(dateString) { //parameter date from form

Comment: please review my code above? because i just only made the birthday form manually using dropdownlist.

Comment: i just copied your code and paste it inside my javascript tag. Should i rename something on your code? or what?

Comment: You have to pass a parameter to the function, like "03/21/1986"