# How do you find a person's age when given the current date and date of birth?

Tags: vb.net, date

I need to make a program where you enter the current date and the user's date of birth and it gives you the user's age in days. I have seen this work for years, but days and months do not seem to work. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

> the user's age in days

You can use [`TimeSpan.Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
Dim span As TimeSpan = currentDate - birthDate
Dim days As Int32 = span.Days
```

For example with my birthdate:

```
Dim currentDate = Date.Now
Dim birthDate = New DateTime(1973, 7, 3)
Dim span As TimeSpan = currentDate - birthDate
Dim days As Int32 = span.Days ' => 14870 omg
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not working. I forgot to mention, I am using VB 2008 Express Edition. Thanks for trying to help though.

Comment: @DeepSeaProgramming: no problem with .NET 3.5 (2008): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days%28v=vs.90%29.aspx Do you get an error?

Comment: I need the program to work using the DateTimePicker, and I think I could get it to work, but the picker uses words for the months. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @DeepSeaProgramming: isn't that a completely different question? Use the `DateTimePicker.Value` property to get the `DateTime`.

Comment: Thanks, got this working now. But is there a way of finding the age in seconds?(the date in ss/mm/hh/dd/mm/yyyy - the dob in dd/mm/yy)

Comment: @DeepSeaProgramming: yes, simply use [`TimeSpan.TotalSeconds`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totalseconds.aspx), so `span.TotalSeconds`.

Comment: @DeepSeaProgramming: what have you tried? A `TimeSpan` has a `TotalSeconds` property. Maybe you have tried `DateTime.TotalSeconds` which does not exist. However, consider to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this: [A Simple Age Calculator Using VB.Net](http://seriouscode.blogspot.in/2011/02/simple-age-calculator-using-vbnet.html)

Code snippet:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim dt1 As Date
    Dim dt2 As Date
    Dim dt3 As TimeSpan
    Dim diff As Double

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        dt1 = Me.DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString
        dt2 = Me.DateTimePicker2.Value.ToShortDateString
        dt3 = (dt2 - dt1)
        diff = dt3.Days
        Me.Label1.Text = ("Your Age is " + Str(Int(diff / 365)) + " Year ")
        diff = diff Mod 365
        Me.Label1.Text = Me.Label1.Text + (Str(Int(diff / 30)) + " Month(s)")
        diff = diff Mod 30
        Me.Label1.Text = Me.Label1.Text + (Str(diff) + " Day(s)")
    End Sub


End Class
```

Use [`TimeSpan.Days`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get time passed from DOB to current date and apply simple formulas to get your desired result.

References:
[compute age from given birthdate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16874911/compute-age-from-given-birthdate)