# VB convert total sum of days to datetime

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have an Excel sheet that i'm trying to transcribe to a VB form in order to get equipment's up time from an input number.

Let's say that the calculation results in, ex: 4.391286731 that is the days total.

In Excel I applied:

```
=INT(col+row) &" Days " & HOUR(col+row) & " h " & MINUTE(col+row) & " m " & SECOND(col+row) & " s".
```

The return is **4 Days 9h 23m 27s** perfect.

Now in VB, after getting the final calculation , ex: the same 4.391286731 how can I convert this total to a date/time format similar to the Excel one above?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get years, months, days for an elapsed span of time (DateTime)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902973/get-years-months-days-for-an-elapsed-span-of-time-datetime)

Comment: assuming that by "VB" you really mean VB.NET (as per the tag) and not excel-vba/vba/vbscript or some other variant

Comment: Just a FYI You could use this in Excel instead, `=TEXT(A1,"d ""Days"" h""h"" m""m"" s""s""")` for a shorter formula.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I find escaping the text with backslashes makes for a cleaner looking format mask.

Comment: @Jeeped something new for me learn. :) `=TEXT(A1,"d \D\a\y\s h\h  m\m s\s")`

Comment: This will also works for me in vb.net `TimeSpan.FromDays(4.391286731).ToString("d\ \d\a\y\s\ h\h\ m\m\ s\s")`

Answer (score 2):

The data type you're looking for is `TimeSpan`.

Convert `Decimal` days to a `TimeSpan`:

```
Dim t As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(4.391286731)
```

New `TimeSpan` from days, minutes, ETC:

```
dim t as new TimeSpan([Days], Hours, Minutes, Seconds)
```

Edit:
`Timespan.ToString()` will give you a string representation, but not in your requested format.

```
string.format("{0:%d} Days {0:%h}h, {0:%m}m, {0:%s}s", timespan.fromdays(4.391286731))
```

Returns: "4 Days 9h, 23m, 27s"

[MSDN Custom TimeSpan Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Format command.

From the Immediate window with `4.391286731` in the [ActiveCell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193314.aspx).

```
?format(int(activecell.Value2), "0 \d\a\y\s ")&format(activecell.Value2, "h\h m\m s\s")
4 days 9h 23m 27s
```

You cannot mix-and-match a **0** format mask with **h**, **m** or **s** but you can certainly concatenate two Format strings together.