# subtract list first element with second one

Tags: c#

Consider that i have   list `dtArray1` that consist of `DateTime` items I mean `10.10.2010`, `10.10.2015` and so on.

Could u say me how find subract of this element ?
How i can get diffeerence between 2 years?

```
for (Int32 index = 1; index < dtArray1.Count;index++)
{
    if (dtArray1[index] >= dtArray1[index - 1])
    {            
        dtArray1[index].Subtract(dtArray1[index - 1]);
        Console.WriteLine(dtArray1[index]);
        Console.ReadLine();
     }
}
```

Comment: What does your current code actually do? What errors does it produce? What output does it produce?

Comment: _"diffeerence between 2 years"_??

Comment: i should get in the output 5 years difference between 10.10.2015 and 10.10.2010 but i get  10.10.2015

Comment: After your last edit the code makes even less sense. Now you are subtrating two datetimes without assigning the result to a variable. `Console.WriteLine(dtArray1)` is pointless since `dtArray1` is a collection. Why have you edited your code in this way?

Answer (score 2):

If your dates are of the `DateTime` type, you can just substract one from the other, like so:

```
var span = dtArray1[index] - dtArray1[index - 1];
Console.WriteLine(span.Days); // prints "1836"
```

The result will be of type [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). TimeSpan does not have a `Years` property, so you'll have to calculate the number of years yourself, keeping in mind leap years and whatnot. See [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1595311/5409)

Comment: but again result is 10.10.2015

Comment: The value of `dtArray1[index]` will still be 10.10.2015, but the value of `span` will be the difference between the two dates.