# Calculate nearest age by birth date in c#

Tags: c#

I want to calculate the age based on birth date and it should rounded to the nearest 
i.e. 19/03/1988 would be resultant into 26 and 19/09/1988 to 25.

Below is the current implementation.

```
var ts = DateTime.Now - dtBirthdate;
var age = ts.Days / 365;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c?rq=1

Comment: When does your current implementation give you incorrect result?

Comment: What problems have you observed in the current implementation? Does it crash? Does it throw an exception? Does it work? It it doesn't, how do its results compare to the expected ones?

Comment: Above code is calculating the age but not the nearest, As per the birth date 19/03/1988, the age should be 26 not 25.

Comment: @AndrewKim: The link you have provided is not calculating the nearest age too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your current implementation is integer division. If you replace with a double, it should work better:

```
var ts = DateTime.Now - new DateTime(1988, 3, 19);
var age = Math.Round(ts.Days / 365.0);
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked for me! The link provided in above comment by Andrew Kim is not working too! I don't know how without knowing people has started down voting this question.