# how to retrieve current age to a textbox from this function?

Tags: c#

```
public static int CalculateAge(DateTime birthdate)
        {
             int years = DateTime.Now.Year - birthdate.Year;
             if (DateTime.Now.Month < birthdate.Month 
             || (DateTime.Now.Month == birthdate.Month 
             && DateTime.Now.Day < birthdate.Day))
             years--;
             return years;
        }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This question is about putting the age value in a textbox, not how to calculate it in the first place.

Comment: Why down-voted? it's a legitimate question!

Comment: I am unsure how the title of the question relates to the posted code and what the OP actually wants to know.

Comment: @user3239745 did any of the provided answers help you? If yes please mark it as accepted answer (click on the tick at the up-vote and down-vote buttons)

Answer (score 3):

Simply do this:

```
textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(CalculateAge(someDate));
```

You have to assign the calculated value to the `Text` property of your textbox. But as the return type of your function is `int` you first have to Convert it to a `string`, as a TextBox can only display strings.

Answer (score 2):

You mean like this ?

```
textBox.Text = CalculateAge(birthDate).ToString();
```