# How to calculate age from date

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I see that this has been asked many times. A lot of people have answered, but i haven't been able to make it work.

This is the code I got from my searches:

```
public static int CalculateAge(DateTime birthDate)
{
    DateTime now = DateTime.Today;
    int years = now.Year - birthDate.Year;

    if (now.Month < birthDate.Month || (now.Month == birthDate.Month && now.Day < birthDate.Day))
        --years;

    return years;
}
```

How do I supply the birth date from a TextBox?

Im using Jquery calender to supply date into a TextBox3 in dd-mm-yy format..

Now I want to calculate age from the supplied date and then on a button click to save in the DB..

I get the save on DB part, but how do I insert TextBox value into the code above and then use years to save it on my button click event?

Comment: Think of this logically. how do you calculate the year difference? Take the current year and subtract that from the supplied year in the DOB. Simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

Comment: Logic isnt the problem, i dunno how to pass the BirthDate from a TextBox into the code above..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So here, how do i supply the birth date from a TextBox?

With *supply*, if you mean to get it's `Text` as `DateTime`, you can parse it to `DateTime` like;

```
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(TextBox3.Text, "dd-MM-yy",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
   // now you can use dt with subtract process as a DateTime
}
```

or if `dd-MM-yy` format is a *standard date and time format* for your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can directly use [`DateTime.Parse()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.DateTime.Parse.aspx) like;

```
var dt = DateTime.Parse(TextBox3.Text);
```

By the way, `mm` specifier is for minutes, `MM` is for months. Don't forget to add [`System.Globalization` namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to use them.

Read also: [Calculate age in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

Comment: Its telling me, CultureInfo does not exist and DateTimeStyles also does not exist...

Comment: @Rifshan Add `System.Globalization` namespace top of your code as `using System.Globalization;`.

Comment: Thanks, What i needed was actually the Parse thing, That did the trick :)