# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in asp.net, hosted on godaddy

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, drop-down-menu, hosting

I have an application where I need to get the years from the Date of Birth, I am using dropdownlist to populate Day, Month and Year. 
I have coded on year dropdownlist selectindexchange event to calculate years  here my code, it runs perfectly when I do it on my development machine but as I host it on godaddy it gives me error :

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

I have tried few steps as in to put cultureinfo which I have comment but even those do not work

```
    protected void DDLyear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        var date = DDLDay.Text + "/" + DDLMonth.Text + "/" + DDLYear.Text;
        DOB.Text = date;
        if (DDLDay.Text == "DD" || DDLMonth.Text == "MM" || DDLYear.Text == "YYYY")
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Invalid Date')</script>");
            DDLYear.Text = "YYYY";
            return;

        }

        if (Convert.ToDateTime(date) > System.DateTime.Now)
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('DOB cannot be greater then current date')</script>");
            //DOB.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
            return;
        }
      //  DateTime now = System.DateTime.Now;
        //DateTime now = DateTime.Parse(System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);
        //DateTime birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DOB.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-IN").DateTimeFormat);
      DateTime now = DateTime.ParseExact(System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        string birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DOB.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
        TimeSpan difference = Convert.ToDateTime(now) - Convert.ToDateTime(birthDate);

        //DateTime birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DOB.Text);
        //TimeSpan difference = Convert.ToDateTime(now) - Convert.ToDateTime(birthDate);
        int days = (int)difference.TotalDays;
        int year = days / 365;
        ////int remain = days % 365;
        ////int month = remain / 30;
        ////int day = remain % 30;

        txtage.Text = year + " " + "Years".ToString();

    }
```

**Stack Trace**

```
[FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.]
System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi,  DateTimeStyles styles) +10973474
 System.Convert.ToDateTime(String value) +83     FAHIS_Data_Entry_Software_in_WEB.NewEnrolee5.DDLyear_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) +397
 System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e) +116
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() +133
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() +13
 System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() +132
 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1644
```

Comment: On which line exactly you get this error? What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: CurrentCultire is `hi-In`,I will post my stack trace

Comment: I am not sure which line it should be according to me `string birthDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DOB.Text).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");`

Comment: What is the value of `DOB.Text` exactly? Debug your code and tell us.

Comment: `DOB.text="01/01/2002"`

Comment: `DOB.Text="01/01/2002"` I have even tried with `DOB.Text="15/01/2002"`

Comment: Why don't you just parse the individual parts? E.g. `Int32.Parse(DDLDay.Text)`

Comment: @mark Are you sure your current culture is `hi-In`? Because both `Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/2002", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-In"))` and `Convert.ToDateTime("15/01/2002", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("hi-In"))` parses fine.

Comment: @SonerGönül no I am not, I previously had textbox which showed calender, but due to client requirement had to change , and I use `hi-In` and it worked fine,so I guessing it should be right

Comment: By the way - you're calculating age incorrectly.  See [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9/634824)

Answer (score 0):

> User Culture Info

```
 cInfo = new CultureInfo("es-AR");
        DateTime DOB= Convert.ToDateTime(DOB.Text, cInfo.DateTimeFormat);
```

Comment: `cInfo = new CultureInfo("es-AR");` do I need to change it to `cInfo = new CultureInfo("hi-In");` ?