# Calculate age in C# using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I want to calculate a customer age based on his birth date.

```
public List<ProductView> GetProductsByStoreAndCategoryID(string storeId, string categoryId)
{
    Authenticate();
    int _storeId = Convert.ToInt32(storeId);
    int _categoryId = Convert.ToInt32(categoryId);

    //selecting customerid
    var _customerId = (from cs in context.customerstores.Where(cs => cs.StoreId == _storeId && cs.IsDefault.Equals(true)) select cs.CustomerId).FirstOrDefault();

    //getting customer date of birth for calculating age and excluding regulated product from the list
    var _DateOfBirth = (from c in context.customers.Where(c => c.CustomerId == _customerId && c.IsBlocked.Equals(false)) select c.DateOfBirth).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Here I am getting the date of birth, after that I want to calculate age based on that date of birth. How to do that?

Comment: Age in what units? Whole years?

Comment: no it should be like 24, 25, etc ...

Comment: That *is* whole years...

Comment: @VijayP.V What would change in the context of question if you removed all the code and leave only `var _DateOfBirth = ......`

Comment: You don't need to use Linq to do this. Just use one of the (many) approaches in the linked thread. Personally I like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16142434/106159) ;)

Comment: @Eser i removed unwanted codes. i want write a logic for the calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be like:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;

var age = today.Year - _DateOfBirth.Year ; ////If _DateOfBirth is a DateTime  object

if (_DateOfBirth > today.AddYears(-age)) age--;
```

Comment: Thanks man.. its working... This is what i wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested... but should work.

```
    public static int GetAge(DateTime customerDateOfBirth)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var customerAge = now.Year - customerDateOfBirth.Year;
        if (customerDateOfBirth > now.AddYears(-customerAge)) 
            customerAge--;
        return customerAge;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _DateOfBirth = (from c in context.customers.Where(c => c.CustomerId == _customerId && c.IsBlocked.Equals(false)) select c.DateOfBirth).FirstOrDefault();
    Console.WriteLine(_DateOfBirth.Year);
    Console.WriteLine(_DateOfBirth.Day);
    Console.WriteLine(_DateOfBirth.Month);
```

You can calculated age from above code