# Difficulty parsing string to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

The following piece of code gives me the following error:

> "Unhandled Exception: string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

There is an unknown word starting at index 0."

How can I convert the string to DateTime properly here?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Exercise
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {  
            Console.Write("Enter your birthday in format(dd.mm.yyyy): ");
            DateTime userBirthday = DateTime.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            long result = DateTime.Today.Subtract(userBirthday).Ticks;
            Console.WriteLine("You are {0} years old.", new DateTime(result).Year - 1);
            Console.WriteLine("After 10 years you will be {0} years old.", new DateTime(result).AddYears(10).Year - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `DateTime.TryParse`/`DateTime.TryParseExact` if you get user input. Apart from that, what did the user give you as input? What is your current date setting(control-panel/region and language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateTime.Parse` uses standard date and time formats of your `CurrentCulture` settings *by default*. Looks like `dd.mm.yyyy` is not one of them.

You can use `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTime.TryParseExact` methods to specifiy your format exactly.

By the way, I *strongly* suspect you mean `MM` (for months) instead of `mm` (for minutes).

```
DateTime userBirthday = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), 
                                            "dd.MM.yyyy", 
                                            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

By the way, calculating age is difficult in programming since it depends on where you were born and where you are right now.

Check this: [Calculate age in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

Answer (score 5):

You can use [ParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w2sa9yss(v=vs.110).aspx) to specify the date format:

```
DateTime userBirthday  = DateTime.ParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;
```

Or [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact(v=vs.110).aspx) if you don'trust the user input:

```
 DateTime userBirthday ; 

 if (!DateTime.TryParseExact(Console.ReadLine(), "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out userBirthday)) 
 {
   Console.WriteLine("You cheated") ; 
   return ; 
 }
```

Available DateTime format can be found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx).