# Exam in Fundamental Object Oriented Programming. Code snippet

Tags: c#, methods

I'm attending an exam at Tuesday in FOOP (described in title), and I've handed in a programme. Problem is that I don't quite understand the following bit. It's a method for calculating a persons age:

```
public static int CalculateAge(DateTime dob)
{
    int years = DateTime.Now.Year - dob.Year;

    if ((dob.Month > DateTime.Now.Month) || (dob.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && dob.Day > DateTime.Now.Day))
        years--;

    return years;
}
```

I couldn't figure it out myself, so I looked it up on the internet. I don't know what happens inside the `if` statement. It should be mentioned that I've a `Datetime` variable called `dob`

Comment: OK today is 18 June 2016. Compare my ages if I was born on 1st January 2000, 17th June 2000, and 19th June 2000

Comment: There is a less confusing way of calculating age, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c

Comment: It is taken from [one of the answers to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

Comment: I think you should just spend more time thinking about this yourself.

Comment: You need a [Rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)

Comment: @Plutonix nice reference to rubber-duck debugging. Have you actually read the pragmatic programmer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What this code is doing, is determining a person's age based on their date-of-birth relative to the current date.

Let's take a look at the first line of code:

```
int years = DateTime.Now.Year - dob.Year;
```

What they are doing on the line above is determining overall how many years that the person has been alive.

Now, let's take a look at the conditions inside of the `if` statement. First, we will take a look at the left-hand-side of the `||` (means *or-else*, but will be treated as *or* for this code-snippet) operator.

```
(dob.Month > DateTime.Now.Month)
```

What this statement does is evaluate whether or not the current month is ahead of the person's birth-month. Then, consider the right-hand-side of the `||` operator.

```
(dob.Month == DateTime.Now.Month && dob.Day > DateTime.Now.Day)
```

The above conditional asks the question of whether or not this is their birth-month, and if so, is their birthday in the *future*? If the answer to either or these conditionals is *yes*, then the person has not reached their birthday. So, we subtract off one year from the total number of years as follows:

```
years--;
```

To help you think about this better, one could ask "just because this is the 16th year you've lived during, does that mean you are actually 16 complete years old?"

Comment: I really think you should have left the OP to think about this for as long as it took.