# Why does my code not calculate the age in number of days?

Tags: c#

My C# code is :

```
private int ageInDays()
{
    string[] month = {"January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"};
    int age = 0;

    DateTime birthDay = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(yearCombo.Text), Array.IndexOf(month, monthCombo.Text) + 1, Convert.ToInt32(dayCombo.Text));
    MessageBox.Show(birthDay.Date.ToString());
    DateTime tempDay = birthDay;
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    while (tempDay != today)
    {
        age++;
        tempDay.AddDays(1);
    }
    return age;   
}
```

When I execute it, the program shows no progress at all. It probably hangs or falls into an infinite loop. Is it due to the heavy amount of processing the program has to do? Why am I not getting any output?

If the above method of calculating the age solely in days is flawed, what's a better/simpler way?

Comment: Hint: `DateTime.AddDays` returns a new value, it doesn't modify the existing value.

Comment: If you debug and step through your program, you can see exactly what is happening instead of guessing.

Comment: You know you can just subtract one `DateTime` from another and get a `TimeSpan` that includes a `Days` property `(today - birthDay).Days`

Comment: Hint2: DateTime has a subtract method that returns a TimeSpan. TimeSpan has a Days property.

Comment: [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DateTime` is an immutable struct. You have to assign what [`DateTime.AddDays`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays(v=vs.110).aspx) returns to the variable:

```
tempDay = tempDay.AddDays(1);
```

You can get the result in an easier and more efficient way with [`TimeSpan.Days`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.days(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
int age = (DateTime.Today - birthDay).Days;
```

Comment: "The DateTime is a struct, hence it's immutable." That's a non-sequitur. Value types can be mutable, e.g. `System.ValueTuple`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: avoided misunderstandings with other formulation

Comment: Right - that's more like it.