# Calculate age in Razor(ASP.NET mvc)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a View with a table

Here is the code of the View:

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td class="point">
            @(rowNo += 1)
        </td>
        <td class="FIO" style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px; cursor:pointer">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FIO) @Html.Hidden("clientEmail", item.FIO)</td>

        <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.City)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Birthday)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salary)
        </td>
        <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.English)
        </td>
      <td style="text-align: end;">
            <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "Interwier", new {id = item.Interwier_id})'>
                <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Edit.png")' />
            </a>
            <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Interwier", new {id = item.Interwier_id})'>
                <img src='@Url.Content("~/Images/Delete.png")' />
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

This code is about Age:

```
<td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;">
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Birthday)
</td>
```

It returns me year from database. I need to show age.

How I can do this correctly?

Comment: By adding a property to the model that calculates it?

Comment: Can I do this on front-end, not on back-end?@SamiKuhmonen

Comment: Why in front End? Bad approach. As mentioned by sami...that's correct

Comment: Sure, you can just add a calculation for it in the view if you want. But why would you?

Comment: Okay. How I can do this on back end? @SamiKuhmonen

add new property for age and calculate `now -  year'?@SamiKuhmonen

Comment: I think you can achieve that by subtracting the Birthday to Date.Now. However if you are retrieving YEAR only for the Birthday you won't get the accurate age. you'll need to get the full BirthDate(YYYY-MM-DD) to get the exact AGE.

Comment: Use jaavscript to calculate age from dob.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/calculate-age-in-c-sharp

Comment: Minor grammatical corrections

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your description, your `Birthday` is a year value you can:

first add a new property in your model used in view for generating `Age`:

```
public class ModelName
{
    // other properties
    // original Birthday property
    public int Birthday {get;set;}

    // get age by subtracting current year with Birthday year.
    public int Aget {get {return DateTime.Now.Year - Birthday;}}
}
```

then in your view

change displaying `Birthday` to `Age`

```
 <td style="text-align: center; font-size: 16px;">
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Age)
 </td>
```