# How to calculate age (in years) based on Date of Birth

Tags: c#, sql

**Problem:** I have a table that list the person DOB.

I have a field (called Person_DOB) that I can use to grab the person DOB from the database. I would like to grab the person year they were born and compare it with the current year we are in.

Ex.
1988-09-26 00:00:00.000

I have a field that I can call that contains the DOB of the person. How can I covert that to a date and calculate their age using C#?

I have tried the following but it appears to not work:

```
<%
int now = int.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
int dob = int.Parse("Person_DOB".ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
int age = (now-dob) / 10000;
Response.Write(age);
%>
```

But I am getting invalid argument error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Paging @JonSkeet for a [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org/) plug

Comment: The `"Person_DOB"` could not be convert to int.

Comment: It's not a direct duplicate because the issue it not only with DateTime.

Comment: @S.Akbari okay....

Comment: `DateTime.Parse` will get you a date. See the duplicate question for how to calculate the age.

Comment: @VladStryapko what is the issue, then? If I understood correctly, OP is trying to convert `DateTime.Now` to string, then convert the date got from database to string, then convert both to integer and calculate age. This can be done in a simpler way, as showed in the other question.

Comment: @Alisson I have tried those approaches and it keeps erroring out

Comment: If you have a string date, you need to parse it to datetime first before you can tostring it to a date format. Probably include `var dateDob = DateTime.Parse(Person_DOB).ToString("yyyyMMdd"); `where Person_DOB has value similar to your example

Comment: @Alisson
I think the question was mistakenly marked by L.B as a duplicate. Here's why: If we go to the 'duplicate' question, we see that it's about comparing two DateTime instances. However, OP's question is more general and even though it results in comparing two DateTime instances, OP cannot simply look up the answer. They will have to ask the next question - how to convert values in the database to DateTime. That's why I don't think it's a direct duplicate. It can be split into 2 question: 1. how to convert values to DateTime and 2. how to compare them, the latter being a 100% duplicate.

Comment: @maccettura - I already have [a NodaTime based answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20715576/634824) in the dup question linked.

Comment: @L.B why was it marked as a duplicate if OP clearly cannot find an answer in the 'duplicate' question without asking additional questions? It cannot be ' an exact duplicate of an existing question'.

Comment: @MattJohnson:  do not really want to use that. I thought there was another approach

Comment: @Lawrence I have tried your approach but it keeps not liking it

Comment: @VladStryapko: Do you have any suggestion to achieve what I am looking for? If not, I will keep looking

Comment: `"Person_DOB".ToString("yyyyMMdd")` << as far as I know this can't work. It looks you are getting the person *DOB* as a string and trying to convert directly. You need something like `DateTime.Parse("Person_DOB").ToString("yyyyMMdd")`, which is what @Lawrence suggested.

Comment: @RobertoFlores

The algorithm's pretty straightforward: 1. Get the DOB from the database 2. Get current DateTime 3. Calculate the age based on the way described in another question. If anything's not clear, ask a separate question about that.

Comment: @Alisson: Again , I have tried that on my end. Keeps not liking it

Comment: Yes, many of the answers in the dup question address how to do the math.  The problem with your code is that `"Person_DOB"` is just a string, it's not pulling out the actual value out of any field.  Assuming you're connecting to a database and have a datareader, it's going to be something like `reader["Person_DOB"]`

Comment: So it sounds like the issue you're having is converting the database value to a `DateTime`. There have been some good suggestions here in the comments about how to do that. At this point, I think you should delete this question, give one of the suggestions a try, and then ask a new question specifically about that, including the actual exception message and stack trace (not just *"it keeps not liking it"*).