# How to do i get my code to calculate the age from birthdate?

Tags: c#, date

```
namespace Computerization_of_Health_Records {
  public class HealthProfile {
    //auto implemented property Firstname implicitly creates an 
    //instance variable for the patients first name
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    //auto implemented property Firstname implicitly creates an 
    //instance variable for the patients last name
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    //auto implemented property Gender implicitly creates an 
    //instance variable for the patients gender
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    //auto implemented property birthday implicitly creates an 
    //instance variable for the patients birth day
    public Int32 Birthday { get; set; }

    //auto implemented property height implicitly creates an 
    //instance variable for the patients height
    public string Height { get; set; }

    //auto implemented property weight implicitly creates an 
    //instance variable for the patients weight
    public string Weight { get; set; }

    public string maxHeartRate { get; set; }

    public string bmi { get; set; }

    public string Age { get; set; }


    //constructor to initialize first name, last name, gender, birthday, birth month,
    //Birth year, height and weight.
    public HealthProfile(string first, string last, string gender, Int32 birthday, string height, string weight, string maxHrtRate) {
      FirstName = first;
      LastName = last;
      Gender = gender;
      Birthday = birthday;
      Height = height;
      Weight = weight;
      maxHeartRate = maxHrtRate;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What's "TIA"? Why so much code unrelated to the problem?

Comment: What does any of the code in the question have to do with calculating a birthdate?

Comment: Your birthday variable is Int32. You won't be able to calculate age unless it's atleast timespan value in there.

Comment: You don't have a birthdate in your code, and you already specify an age.  Please correct the question to be reasonable and reduce the amount of code that is unneeded.  It's confusing the situation.

Comment: Why would `Age` be a `string` property?

Comment: Use some common sense.  How would you calculate someone's age if you were doing it manually using a pencil and paper?  Figure that out and write down the steps.  Then translate those steps to code.  If you have trouble translating any of the steps to code, then ask a question about that step.

Comment: @tadman: TIA = [thanks in advantage](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288160/no-thanks-damn-it). Great that we have it in titles now.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I'll just remove that from the title and pretend we never saw it. Yikes.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1):

Pass date of birth to the below function in UTC format(as it is a standard date format).

```
public static string GetAge(DateTime dob)
{
    DateTime todayDateUtc = DateTime.UtcNow;
    DateTime pastYearDate;
    int years = 0;
    string age;
    int days;

    if(DateTime.UtcNow > dob) {
        years = new DateTime(DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(dob).Ticks).Year - 1;
    }

    pastYearDate = dob.AddYears(years);
    days = todayDateUtc.Subtract(pastYearDate).Days;
    age = years + " years " + days + " days";

    return age;
}
```