# How to subtract int Year(from user input) from DateTime.Now.Year?

Tags: c#, datetime, int, subtraction

I have a method Age() that returns the age of a car( subtracted from the year of production which is an int based on user input and it has to be an int).

Also, from this method I raise an event that shows me the age of the car. I only need the year, no months or days. My code is something like this and it's not working.The event is raised, but no value is shown. No errors in the code.

```
public int Age()
{

int Year= DateTime.Now.Year; // only the year in int

int YIP=Year-Year of production; // Year of production from user input

return YIP;

}
```

Comment: `DateTime result = DateTime.Now.AddYear(-1);`

Comment: *My code is something like this and it's not working.* What doesn't work?

Comment: Post a [mcve] .

Comment: Are you getting any error? Post the related piece of code too, then only someone would be able to help you.

Comment: I'm not getting any errors(and it's weird ), even with code like this. I'm just a beginner trying to learn. 
The event is raised, but no value is shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I calculate someone's age in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9/how-do-i-calculate-someones-age-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `AddYears` with a negative value for year:

```
var myNewDateMinusOneYear = Datetime.Today.AddYears(-1)
```

**Additional resources**

[DateTime.AddYears Method (Int32)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Returns a new DateTime that adds the specified number of years to the
>   value of this instance.
>
> **Return Value** Type: System.DateTime An object whose value is the sum of the date and time represented by this instance and the number
>   of years represented by value.
>
> **Remarks** This method does not change the value of this DateTime object.
>   Instead, it returns a new DateTime object whose value is the result of
>   this operation.

Comment: This sounds more like a rant than an answer. Please [*Be Nice*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @PatrickHofman nah, someone upvoted i'm still not a multiple of 5 though so this will have to go

Comment: You could also turn this into a non-rant answer.

Comment: @PatrickHofman advice taken, and sanitized

Comment: @PatrickHofman thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the below code, it should help you.

```
var previousYear = System.DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1);
```